# inverse=true in JPA annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inverse, hibernate-onetomany

In my application I use JPA 2.0 with Hibernate as the persistence provider. I have a one-to-many relationship between two entities (using a `@JoinColumn` and not `@JoinTable`). I wanted to know how could I specify `inverse=true` (as specified in `hbm.xml`) in JPA annotations to reverse the relationship owner.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achive?

Comment: As you know inverse controls which entity in the relationship updates the foreign key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439756/hibernate-inverse-in-mapping-file. In my one-to-many relationship I want to specify this.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I found an answer to this. The mappedBy attribute of @OneToMany annotation behaves the same as inverse = true in the xml file.

Comment: Also, this question has more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby.

Answer (score 4):

The attribute `mappedBy` indicates that the entity in this side is the inverse of the relationship, and the owner resides in the other entity. Other entity will be having `@JoinColumn` annotaion and `@ManyToOne` relationship. Hence I think inverse = true is same as `@ManyToOne` annotation.

Also inverse=”true” mean this is the relationship owner to handle the relationship.

Answer (score 3):

by using **mappedBy** attribute of **@OneToMany** or **@ManyToMany** we can enable inverse="true" in terms of annotation.
For example Branch and Staff having one-to-many relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "branch")
public class Branch implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "branch_no")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected int branchNo;
    @Column(name = "branch_name")
    protected String branchName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch") // this association is mapped by branch attribute of Staff, so ignore this association
    protected Set<Staff> staffSet;
    
    // setters and getters
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "staff")
public class Staff implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "staff_no")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected int staffNo;
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    protected String fullName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "branch_no", nullable = true)
    protected Branch branch;

    // setters and getters
}
```