# How to define unidirectional OneToMany relationship in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a following problem with entity mapping in JPA. I have two entities, first one is Lookup and the second is Text which represents translations for entities. Now I need to bound Lookup to the Text but I don't want Text to have reference to Lookup. To make this more complicated, Text does not use its primary key in this relationship but a metacode defined in a  `TXTHEAD_CODE` column.

`Lookup.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DATREG")
public class Lookup implements PersistableEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATREG_META_CODE")
    private String metaCode;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="TXT", 
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DATREG_META_CODE", referencedColumnName="TXTHEAD_CODE"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DATREG_META_CODE"))
    private List<Text> text;
```

`Text.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TXT")
public class Text {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TXT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TXTHEAD_CODE")
    private String code;
```

So I have tried this (and few other variations) but with no result. I also can't create join table in the DB and I don't want bound Lookup to my Text class. So can anyone please tell me if there is some other way?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

My bible for JPA work is the [Java Persistence wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence). It has a [section on unidirectional `OneToMany`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Undirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29) which explains how to do this with a `@JoinColumn` annotation. In your case, i think you would want:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="TXTHEAD_CODE")
private Set<Text> text;
```

I've used a `Set` rather than a `List`, because the data itself is not ordered.

The above is using a defaulted `referencedColumnName`, unlike the example in the wikibook. If that doesn't work, try an explicit one:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="TXTHEAD_CODE", referencedColumnName="DATREG_META_CODE")
private Set<Text> text;
```

Comment: Wow, it really worked, thank you. I thought that I always need to create a join table if there is only one side of the relationship (the other side does not hold the foreign keys).

Comment: Bingo! This "Java Persistence Wikibook" link is what i have been looking for... Thanks for sharing...

Comment: I'm trying the same but, the foreign key is not getting set in the child entity in the DB, I'm getting this exception: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into`

Comment: @SandeepKumar What do you mean by "child entity"? The equivalent of `Text` in this example? I suspect that JPA does not consider the referenced column to be a foreign key, in which case it won't populate it with the ID of the parent; i'm afraid you will have to set it yourself before saving.

Comment: I fixed the issue by removing the property from my child class. Now, JPA is implicitly considering the key mentioned in the parent class and inserting the value. Thanks!