# Mapping a list of entities by a non key property

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having the database below (simplified):

```
Translation( id, language, text)
StoryChapter (id, chapterTitle)
```

The `Translation` primary key is `(id, language)`

Here's what I got so far in Java:

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(TranslationId.class)
public class Translation {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Id
    private String language;

    @Lob
    private String text;
    
}

public class TranslationId implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String language;

}


@Entity
public class StoryChapter {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "chapter_title",
            referencedColumnName = "id"
    )
    private List<Translation> chapterTitle;

}
```

My only concern with this code is that it requires a new table to join `StoryChapter` and `Translation`, and I'd like to avoid this behavior (but go along with it if it's really impossible).

Using `OneToMany` is also a no-go because it requires additional columns within `Translation` table, and this table will be used by many other entities later on.

So, with data example, if a have in my `Translation` table:

| id | language | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EN | This is a chapter title ! |
| 1 | FR | C'est un titre de chapitre ! |
| 2 | EN | And another one ! |
| 2 | FR | Et un autre ! |

I'd like my `StoryChapter` to be like:

| id (PK) | chapterTitle |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

And in Java, my `chapterTitle` list should have the two entries (the two languages available).

Is this behavior even possible with JPA ?

**Solution**

Thanks to Martin'sRun who gave me valuable informations to solve my problem.

For each `Set` added, a corresponding field need to be created, which will hold the raw value:

```java
    private long chapterTitle;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "chapterTitle")
    private Set<Translation> chapterTitles;
```

At that point, the tables in database looked like I wanted. But upon using findAll(), this error was thrown:

```
StoryChapter cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable
```

I just added `implements Serializable` to my class.

Then, another error poped-up:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: StoryChapter.chapterTitles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

So I just added `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` on the `@OneToMany` annotation.

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Does the Id column on StoryChapter  represent a foreign-key relation to id on translation table in the example? How is the relation between the tables established?

Comment: @Martin'sRun Sorry, I made a mistake in the example by putting 2 times "1" as ID. The column id on StoryChapter is the ID of that table, I'd like to "simulate" a FK from chapterTitle to the translation id (list of translation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Translation table looks to be a generic text translations, which could be referenced from multiple entities. This relation between *StoryChapter* and *Translation* is uni-directional and one-to-many, is supported on JPA.

Story chapter can reference a collection of Translations with:

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "chapterTitle")
    private Set<Translation> chapterTitle;
```

Other entities which use the translation table can do the same as well.

Check this SO post for more details and documentation [How to define unidirectional OneToMany relationship in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038380/how-to-define-unidirectional-onetomany-relationship-in-jpa)

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! I updated my post to reflect all edits I needed to do for this solution to work !