# Hibernate sometimes tries to delete the parent, then the child entities instead of the other way around

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

### Update: So after more investigating it appears to actually be related to the fact that only 256 items are being returned. Started a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085651/getting-a-256-item-limit-with-spring-hibernate-jpa-mysql

We are having an intermittent issue with Spring 3.2.4, Hibernate 4.2.5, mySql 5.5. Every once in awhile (we haven't found out why yet) when removing an aggregate entity, hibernate will send a sql command to first delete the parent, and then try to delete the children.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activeOrder")
public class ActiveOrder extends AbstractEntity{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lastModifiedUser_id", nullable = false)
    private User lastModifiedUser;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usedOrderSheet_id", nullable = false)
    private OrderSheet usedOrderSheet;

    @Column(name = "lastModifiedTimestamp", nullable = false)
    private Date lastModifiedTimestamp;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "activeOrder_id", nullable = false)
    @BatchSize(size=25)
    private List<ActiveOrderItem> activeOrderItems = new ArrayList<ActiveOrderItem>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private OrderStatus status;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "activeOrderItem")
public class ActiveOrderItem extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fooBar_id", nullable = false)
    private FooBar item;

    @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = false)
    int quantity = 0;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "someOtherItem_id", nullable = true)
    private SomeOtherItem someOtherItem
}
```

The sql that get's generated looks something like this:

```
delete from activeOrder where id = 1;
delete from activeOrderItem where id= 123;
delete from activeOrderItem where id= 124;
delete from activeOrderItem where id= 125;
etc....
```

This is obviously backwards as we need to delete the items first, and then the order. I got the sql statements from the mysql general log table.

What's weird is that it doesn't do this all the time, only occasionally.

When it happens we get this stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:643)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:105)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.services.ActiveOrderWebService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e3fde712.postActiveOrderDetails(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor429.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1771)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3343)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3546)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`siftit`.`activeorderitem`, CONSTRAINT `fk_activeOrderItem_activeOrder` FOREIGN KEY (`activeOrder_id`) REFERENCES `activeorder` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    ... 96 more
```

Any ideas one what we are doing incorrectly, and why this happens? We have a lot of other entities that are mapped in a similar fashion and they've never had an issue like this.

Comment: The link to *Getting a 256 item limit with Spring/Hibernate/Jpa/MySql* is broken. Update ur question with working one.

Answer (score 3):

What we need is to make the `ActiveOrderItem` aware of its parent `ActiveOrder`. Then, we will use the `inverse="true"` mapping, instructing the Hibernate, to correctly work with collections during deletion.

See some more explanation here: [JPA JoinColumn vs mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11938290/1679310), and also here: [Hibernate: Annotation one-to-many/many-to-one](http://tadtech.blogspot.cz/2007/09/hibernate-annotation-many-to-many.html)

the draft of the mapping ActiveOrder:

```
@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="activeOrder")
@BatchSize(size=25)
private List<ActiveOrderItem> activeOrderItems = new ArrayList<ActiveOrderItem>();
```

and the ActiveOrderItem:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="activeOrder_id") 
private ActiveOrder activeOrder;
```

The rest will be done for us by Hibernate, see the [11.10. Flushing the Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-flushing) to get more details about the ORDER of the session flushing (during deletion)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just to make sure I understand correctly from the chapter you mention. The reason that the delete happens in the opposite order is due to the fact that the first delete called in code was actually the parent object, and the subsequent deletes were the children according to the flushing rules. Is this correct? Also is there any reason why the deletes wouldn't always behave this way? We know that we can delete the ActiveOrder just using the parent agg. without issue most of the time. Only occasionally does it fail.

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately I did not work, even with the bi-directional mapping and the mappedBy set in the parent agg, the same issue occurs.

Comment: Extract from the documentation, the order of flushing is: *...3. all collection deletions...6. all entity deletions.* So, if the collection is mapped as shown above, and only root aggregate is deleted: `session.delete(activeRecord)`, Hibernate will for sure delete all included objects in correct order. Firstly collection items *(the `inverse="true"` is also very important to execute just one delete, no update)*, and then, when referencing collection items are off the DB, parents are removed. Please, try to double check your code for deletion. It should work. Hibernate is well designed...

Comment: I have a similar problem.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454703/constraint-violation-when-persisting-one-to-many-relation