# ValidationException Exception Description: uses a non-entity as target entity in the relationship attribute

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I am getting the following exception and have done all this 1000 times before but now I am getting errors:

ValidationException Exception Description: [class com.smartphonedev.rsvplaw.entities.Staff] uses a non-entity [class com.smartphonedev.rsvplaw.entities.Address] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field addresses]..

here are the entities in question.  Can someone help me identify what is wrong with my relationships?

```
<code>
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address implements Serializable,
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name="addressType")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private AddressType addressType;

@Column(name="streetLineOne")
private String streetLineOne;

@Column(name="streetLineTwo")
private String streetLineTwo;

@Column(name="city")
private String city;

@Column(name="adState")
private String state;

@Column(name="postCode")
private String postCode;    

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=PhoneNumber.class, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,   CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH},orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="phoneNumbers")
private Collection<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
…..
}

@Entity
@Table(name="staff")
public class Staff implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

//private Profile profile;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinColumn(name="permission")
private Permission permission;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinColumn(name="login")    
private Login login;

@Column(name="firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="surnameName")
private String surnameName;

@Column(name="emailAddress")
private String emailAddress;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=PhoneNumber.class, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH},orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="phoneNumbers")
private Collection<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Address.class, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH},orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="addresses")
private Collection<Address> addresses;
}
</code
```

Adding the phoneNumber class
    
    `@Entity
    @Table(name="phone")
    public class PhoneNumber implements Serializable
    {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;`

```
@Column(name="numberType")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private PhoneNumberType numberType;

@Column(name="phoneNumber")
private String phoneNumber;
}
</code>
```

Adding persistance.xml

```
<code>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="RSVPLawServerPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/RSVPLaw</jta-data-source>
<class>com.smartphonedev.rsvplaw.entities.PhoneNumber</class>
<class>com.smartphonedev.rsvplaw.entities.Address</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
<validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>  
  <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>

<code>
```

Comment: `@OneToMany` should be `mappedBy`, while `@ManyToOne` should be followed by `@JoinColumn`

Comment: @guido OneToMany has "mappedBy" ONLY IF it is bidirectional ... so how do you know it is in this case when he doesnt show the PhoneNumber class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Comment: Please note they are all unidirectional

Comment: Is your class `Address` listed in the `persistence.xml` ? Looks like it's not "known" to be an entity.

Comment: I also noticed that the Address table is not being created where the PhoneNumber one is.  This is doing my head in :(

Comment: There's this comma after `implements Serializable` (suspect this is just from copy/pasting the code here). Also value `create` for `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` doesn't do updates to the schema, so try `drop-and-create`. If that doesn't help try to crank up the log level and see what output you get.

Answer (score 3):

I am in this same situation while separating a `@ManyToMany` relationship into two `@OneToMany/@ManyToOne` relationships, and I solved it. Here's some tips, concluded from all answers above, and my discovery:

1. make sure the class is with annotation `@Entity`, and has correct `Table(name=xxx)`.
2. If using JPA, make sure it's in `persistence.xml`. If using Hibernate, make sure it's in `hibernate.cfg.xml`. If using both, in both files.
3. Make sure the classes is in the same JAR as the mapping/cfg files.
4. One thing I found: **You don't have to remove `mappedBy=`, but you have to ensure, that the attribute name is unique in your whole project!**

Like in my case: if I remove `mappedBy` in my `@OneToMany` side(while `@ManyToOne` side is a intermediate class for a `@ManyToMany` relationship, which has its own fields, so I have to make it `@Entity` instead of using middle table directly), EclipseLink complains for a table named "EntityA_MiddleEntity", which doesn't exist. I guess, when encountering `mappedBy=xxx`, EclipseLink looks for all entities with fields named `xxx`, and when it exists in more than one class, and one of these classes is the intermediate class for `@ManyToMany`, it fails to relate them. So I changed the attribute name in the middle class and all works fine.