# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: is not a column in table

Tags: jpa, glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6

I'm working on a JavaEE application using EJB and JPA

Two of my Entities are:

```
@Entity
public class Utente implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Utente [cod_utente=" + cod_utente + ", nome_utente="
            + nome_utente + ", morada_utente=" + morada_utente
            + ", dnasc_utente=" + dnasc_utente + ", tel_utente="
            + tel_utente + "]";
}

/**
 * 
 */

public Utente(String nome_utente, String morada_utente,
        GregorianCalendar dnasc_utente, int tel_utente) {
    super();
    this.nome_utente = nome_utente;
    this.morada_utente = morada_utente;
    this.dnasc_utente = dnasc_utente;
    this.tel_utente = tel_utente;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cod_utente;
private String nome_utente;
private String morada_utente;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private GregorianCalendar dnasc_utente;
private int tel_utente;
private List<GregorianCalendar> agenda;
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(nullable=true)
private List<Prescricao> lista_presc;

public Utente(){
    super();
}

public List<Prescricao> getLista_presc() {
    return lista_presc;
}

public void setLista_presc(List<Prescricao> lista_presc) {
    this.lista_presc = lista_presc;
}

public List<GregorianCalendar> getAgenda() {
    return agenda;
}

public void setAgenda(List<GregorianCalendar> agenda) {
    this.agenda = agenda;
}

public int getCod_utente() {
    return cod_utente;
}

public void setCod_utente(int cod_utente) {
    this.cod_utente = cod_utente;
}

public String getNome_utente() {
    return nome_utente;
}

public void setNome_utente(String nome_utente) {
    this.nome_utente = nome_utente;
}

public String getMorada_utente() {
    return morada_utente;
}

public void setMorada_utente(String morada_utente) {
    this.morada_utente = morada_utente;
}

public GregorianCalendar getDnasc_utente() {
    return dnasc_utente;
}

public void setDnasc_utente(GregorianCalendar dnasc_utente) {
    this.dnasc_utente = dnasc_utente;
}

public int getTel_utente() {
    return tel_utente;
}

public void setTel_utente(int tel_utente) {
    this.tel_utente = tel_utente;
}   
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class FichaClinica implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
 * 
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cod_ficha;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn
private Utente utente;
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(nullable=true)
private List <AtoEnfermagem> lista_atos_enf;
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(nullable=true)
private List <AtoMedico> lista_atos_medicos;
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(nullable=true)
private List<Consulta> lista_consultas;

public FichaClinica(){ //construtor vazio
    super();
}

public Utente getUtente() {
    return utente;
}

public void setUtente(Utente utente) {
    this.utente = utente;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "FichaClinica [cod_ficha=" + cod_ficha + ", lista_atos_enf="
            + lista_atos_enf + ", lista_atos_medicos=" + lista_atos_medicos
            + ", lista_consultas=" + lista_consultas + "]";
}

public FichaClinica(Utente utente){
    super();
    this.utente=utente;
}

public FichaClinica(Utente utente,
        ArrayList<AtoEnfermagem> lista_atos_enf,
        ArrayList<AtoMedico> lista_atos_medicos,
        ArrayList<Consulta> lista_consultas) {
    super();
    this.lista_atos_enf = lista_atos_enf;
    this.lista_atos_medicos = lista_atos_medicos;
    this.lista_consultas = lista_consultas;
}

//Adicionar elementos às listas

public int getCod_ficha() {
    return cod_ficha;
}

public void setCod_ficha(int cod_ficha) {
    this.cod_ficha = cod_ficha;
}

public List<AtoEnfermagem> getLista_atos_enf() {
    return lista_atos_enf;
}

public void setLista_atos_enf(List<AtoEnfermagem> lista_atos_enf) {
    this.lista_atos_enf = lista_atos_enf;
}

public List<AtoMedico> getLista_atos_medicos() {
    return lista_atos_medicos;
}

public void setLista_atos_medicos(ArrayList<AtoMedico> lista_atos_medicos) {
    this.lista_atos_medicos = lista_atos_medicos;
}

public List<Consulta> getLista_consultas() {
    return lista_consultas;
}

public void setLista_consultas(ArrayList<Consulta> lista_consultas) {
    this.lista_consultas = lista_consultas;
}

public void adicionar_ato_medico(AtoMedico a_medico){
    lista_atos_medicos.add(a_medico);
}

public void adiconar_consulta(Consulta c){
    lista_consultas.add(c);
}

public void adicionar_ato_enf(AtoEnfermagem a_enf){
    lista_atos_enf.add(a_enf);
}
}
```

When I try to execute the following method:

```
 @Override
 public String cria_utente(String nome_utente, String morada_utente,GregorianCalendar dnasc_utente, int tel_utente) {
    Utente u=new Utente(nome_utente,morada_utente,dnasc_utente,tel_utente);
    em.persist(u);
    FichaClinica fc=new FichaClinica(u);
    em.persist(fc);
    return "Utente "+Integer.toString(u.getCod_utente())+" (Ficha Clinica "+Integer.toString(fc.getCod_ficha())+")  cirado!";
 }
```

An error occurs. Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:725)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy238.cria_utente(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:490)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
... 24 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'UTENTE_COD_UTENTE' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.FICHACLINICA'.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO FICHACLINICA (COD_FICHA, UTENTE_COD_UTENTE) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(FichaClinica [cod_ficha=10, lista_atos_enf={[]}, lista_atos_medicos={[]}, lista_consultas={[]}])
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:696)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
... 26 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'UTENTE_COD_UTENTE' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.FICHACLINICA'.
Error Code: 20000
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:193)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:138)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3168)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:352)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'UTENTE_COD_UTENTE' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.FICHACLINICA'.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:586)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:255)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:52)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:992)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:173)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1556)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1505)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:619)
... 58 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: 'UTENTE_COD_UTENTE' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.FICHACLINICA'.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
... 68 more
```

Can please someone help me find what's wrong here?

Comment: `'UTENTE_COD_UTENTE' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.FICHACLINICA'.` Does this makes sense?

Comment: Maybe. I don't understand why that happens beacause I have a relation to UTENTE using `@OneToOne @JoinColumn private Utente utente`. But I don't know if that is correct. This is the first time that I work with this kind of applications, so I have lack of basic knowledge.

Comment: Forget about your code. Focus on the error message. It says: 'UTENTE_COD_UTENTE' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.FICHACLINICA'. That means that there is no column named UTENTE_COD_UTENTE in the table named FICHACLINICA. I don't see how the message could be clearer. To fix the problem, add the missing column, or fix your mapping so that it matches with the actual column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you probably didn't create the column `UTENTE_COD_UTENTE` in the table `APP.FICHACLINICA`. Creating the column (type integer) should fix the problem.

The code:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn
private Utente utente;
```

doesn't specify a **name** for the join column and therefore creates a default join column based on this rule (from [@JoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name())):

> Default (only applies if a single join column is used): The
>   concatenation of the following: the name of the referencing
>   relationship property or field of the referencing entity or embeddable
>   class; "*"; the name of the referenced primary key column. If there is
>   no such referencing relationship property or field in the entity, or
>   if the join is for an element collection, the join column name is
>   formed as the concatenation of the following: the name of the entity;
>   "*"; the name of the referenced primary key column.

You can set a **name** for the join column like this:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SOMETHING_UTENTE")
private Utente utente;
```

But then you'll have to create a column named like this.

**See also:**

- [JPA JoinColumn vs mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)