# Cannot find column [id] for OneToOne?

Tags: jpa, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Model
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy= "user", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name="info_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
  public Info info;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="infos")
public class Info extends Model
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="info",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  public User user;
}
```

And in my migration, `users` table includes a `info_id` column of bigint type, and `infos` table includes a `user_id` column of bigint type.

However, when i run the application, it gives me `PersistenceException: Error with the Join on [models.Info.user]. Could not find the matching foreign key for [id] in table[users]? Perhaps using a @JoinColumn with the name/referencedColumnName attributes swapped?`

Can anyone provide some insight into what's wrong in my code and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: can you post your schema for these two table?

Comment: remove mappedBy in both entity

Comment: No do NOT remove mappedBy in BOTH entities; remove it from ONE side. It is used to mark a relation as bidirectional and is put on the non-owner side ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**User Model**

```
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="info_id")
  public Info info;
```

**Info Model**

```
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
  public User user;
```

You shouldn't use `mappedBy` along with `JoinColumn`. See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby).