# How to set relationship between tables Ebean/Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean, playframework-2.3

I'm new to Ebean's world, and I encounter some difficulties to set some relationships between entities.

I have basically two classes, `User` and `Car`.

A user can have *several* cars (so I guess `OneToMany`) and a car can belongs to *one* User (so I guess `OneToOne`).

How can I link these two entities? Here it is what I've done so far

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;  
    public String name; 
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Car> car = new ArrayList<Car>();
}
```

**Car**

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public User user; 
}
```

And I get the following error

> PersistenceException: Error on models.User.car Can not find mappedBy
>   property [users] in [models.Car]

Can someone explain me clearly how to use annotations the correct way (very poor documentation), and tell me why I get this error?

Comment: wrong mapping both entity says different relation between each other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You guessed wrong :)

Your `User` should have a `@OneToMany` relationship with cars so:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Car> car = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

while your `Car` should have a `@ManyToOne` relationship    :

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public User user;
```

Take care on the `mappedBy` property in the `@OneToMany` annotation: you need to tell Ebean where the foreign key lies in the related class.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me more the mappedBy parameters? Is it a random name? I don't understand how and when I should use it.

Comment: The mappedBy is not needed in this case because it can be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int id;  
public String name; 
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Car> car = new ArrayList<Car>();
}
```

**Car**

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int id;
@ManyToOne(mappedBy="car")          //will give you an error
public User user; 
}
```

`mappedBy` here represents the owner of relation which is important in bidirectional relation.

Think in normal condition can a car exist without the User which owns it means User is the owner in a relation.So in your case User is the owner of relation.[Mapped By](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)

But the above code will not work `The attribute mappedBy is undefined for the annotation type ManyToOne`

In that case `@JoinColumn` come into picture.[Join Column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11939045/3841803)

Comment: I think finally get the logic. A car cannot exists without a User, this means the User is the owner of the relation, am I right?

Comment: @Mornor you are right .Entity is a POJO(plain old java object) so you can relate it to OOPs like Parent and child class we use to study.Also you should be careful in using cascade in your relation like in my answer I only put cascade type all(means persist,delete etc) to User so if you delete User all the respective cars would be deleted but you dont want that behaviour in Car(that completely depends on your relation).

Comment: You wrote the mappedBy into the Car class. So the owner of the relation is the User (because a car cannot exist without user). To be brief, the mappedBy has to be written in the class which is NOT the owner, right? MappedBy is undefined for ManyToOne annotation.