# Persist 1-m entities with composite primary key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have below 1-m relationship on entities which Mentor to Students. The mentor has composite primary key which i use as foreign key in student

```
@Entity
public class Mentor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private MentorPK id;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mentor")
    private Set<Student> students;

    public MentorPK getId() {
        return id;
    }            
    //getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
public class MentorPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String add;
    //getters and setters
    //override equals and hashcode
}


@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;    

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("id")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="name_fk", referencedColumnName="name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="address_fk", referencedColumnName="address")
    })
    private Mentor mentor;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

I then persist the above as below but only the mentor is persisted where student table is empty.

How can I persist the mentor with students?

```
Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

Student s1 = new Student();
s1.setName("Student 1");

Student s2 = new Student();
s2.setName("Student 2");

students.add(s1);
students.add(s2);

MentorPK mpk = new MentorPK();
mpk.setAddress("C");
mpk.setName("D");

Mentor m = new Mentor();
m.setId(mpk);
m.setEmail("emaill");
m.setStudents(students);

studentManager.saveMentor(m);
```

Comment: Perhaps this is actually an issue with the automatic generation of the Student's Id primary key. Can you create Students without Mentors?

Comment: @DuncanKinnear yes i can

Answer (score 2):

Try changing annotation of students field to

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="mentor", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`

Comment: did not work by adding cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST attribute

Comment: I have just created a small sample project using code you provided (fixing address/add field name inconsistency and removing obsolete @MapsId annotation) and adding the cascade type and it worked as expected, after calling entityManager.persist(m) the students were persisted as well.

Comment: I have just noticed that you mention hibernate, I have created the example using eclipselink. You may want to try using latest version and if it is still not working for you then check if this is a reported bug or report it as a bug yourself.

Comment: Why would `CascadeType.PERSIST` be preferred over `CascadeType.ALL` in this case?  Based upon the data model provided the `Mentor` "owns" their associated `Students`, so it's reasonable to expect `delete` operations to cascade as well.

Comment: i guess Students own the relationship know because foreign keys resides on Students side

Comment: @aroth I just proposed PERSIST since this was what was asked in the original question, ALL would be fine as well, it all depends on the design of the application.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a composite-key, mapped as an Embeddable you need to use [@EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html):

```
@Entity
public class Mentor {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MentorPK id;

    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mentor")
    private Set<Student> students;

    public MentorPK getId() {
        return id;
    }            
    //getters and setters
}
```

and the Student becomes:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="name_fk", referencedColumnName="name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="address_fk", referencedColumnName="address")
    })
    private Mentor mentor;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

The `@MapsId` is used when both the `@Id` and the `@ManyToOne` share the same database columns, which is not your case, since you have a numeric identifier and a composite foreign-key.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to create the reference from Student to Mentor in each Student.

So in your code, after you create `m` you need to:

```
s1.setMentor(m);
s2.setMentor(m);
```

Otherwise Hibernate may not know what to populate columns `name_fk` and `address_fk` with.

Comment: didnt work like that also. i guess i have to persist the student first and then persist the mentor with students

Answer (score 1):

How about changing:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="mentor")
private Set<Student> students;
```

to:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="mentor")
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet();
```

or

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
@org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(name="idx") 
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet();
```

also try not to skip

```
 = new HashSet();
```

part

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your request, you would like to have the Mentor be the owner of the relationship. You do not obtain this with the line `@OneToMany(mappedBy="mentor")`. This actually puts the Student as the owner of the relation.

I have tested this domain model and did a few modifications to the annotations in order to have the test code work as you expect.

**Student**

```java
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="name_fk", referencedColumnName="name", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="address_fk", referencedColumnName="address", insertable = false, updatable = false )
    })
    private Mentor mentor;

//setters and getters
}
```

**Mentor**

```java
public class Mentor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private MentorPK id;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="name_fk", referencedColumnName="name"),
            @JoinColumn(name="address_fk", referencedColumnName="address")
    })
    private Set<Student> students;
//setters and getters
}
```

It even works without doing:`s1.setMentor(m);s2.setMentor(m);`. I did not expect it but it seems that hibernate is dealing with this.

A related article is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby).

**Attention:**  drop the database tables after you change the annotations in order to allow hibernate to recreate the tables.

Comment: Thank. But actually i want student to be the owner of the relationship. That is why i put mappedBy in Mentor side. So i think the model is correct but the way i persist the data in client is wrong. Can you answer how to persist  the student with mentor in correct way

Comment: I try below, Student s1 = new Student();
s1.setName("Student 1");
  
MentorPK mpk = new MentorPK();
mpk.setAddress("C");
mpk.setName("D");

Mentor m = new Mentor();
m.setId(mpk);
m.setEmail("emaill");
  
s1.setMentor(m);

//studentManager.saveMentor(m);
studentManager.saveStudent(s1);                                                                     But it gave me "EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.ejb.entities.Mentor with id com.ejb.entities.MentorPK@c22". Then i persist the mentor before save student. Then i got cannot insert NULL into ("SYS"."STUDENT"."ADDRESS_FK") exception