# JPA mapping annotation error org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I can't propper map DB tables with JPA annotation.
[image: db]

Tables **Subject** and **Place** is ManyToMany through **JoinTable**.

**Subject.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJECT")
public class Subject implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SID")
    private Integer sid;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**SubjectPlace.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJECT_PLACE")
public class SubjectPlace implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SPID")
    private Integer spid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUB_KEY") //Subject FK
    private Subject subject;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLC_KEY") //Place FK
    private Place place;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Place.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLACE")
public class Place implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PID")
    private Integer pid;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinTable(name = "SUBJECT_PLACE",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PLC_KEY", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SUB_KEY", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Subject> subjects;

    // getters and setters
}
```

But than I need to link **Person** with **Subject** in selected Places. I mean that each **Place** has its own collection of **Subject**. And a Person have link to Subject whitch resides in particular Place.

like This:

`Subject (M) -- (M) Place` through JoinTable `Subject (1) -- (M) Subject_Place (M) -- (1) Place`

`Person (M) -- (M) Subject_Place` through JoinTable `Person (1) -- (M) Person_Subject_Place (M) -- (1) Subject_Place`

**Person.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRSID")
    private Integer prsid;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    // How to annotate this code?
    // I experience problem in this part of code
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="SPID_KEY") 
    private List<SubjectPlace> subjectPlaces;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**PersonSubjectPlace.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_SUBJECT_PLACE")
public class PersonSubjectPlace implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PSPID") // Person_Subject_Place ID
    private Integer pspid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PER_KEY") //Person FK
    private Person person;

    // How to annotate this code?
    // I experience problem in this part of code
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SPID_KEY") //Subject_Place FK
    private SubjectPlace subjectPlace;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And when I try so get Persons and its Subjects, I get this error:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK2C3B79384AABC975:PERSON_SUBJECT_PLACE [SPID_KEY])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (SUBJECT_PLACE [PLC_KEY,SUB_KEY])`

What, How shoul I map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OneToMany` mapping you don't need to specify the foreign key, you just need to use `mappedBy` property to refer your mapping object, you can learn more about it in [**OneToMany Mapping Documentation**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association), and here's what you need to map `Person` and `PersonSubjectPlace` entities:

**In your Person class:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
private List<PersonSubjectPlace> personsubjectPlaces;
```

**In your PersonSubjectPlace class:**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PRSID") //Specify the primary key of Person
private Person person;
```

For further information about the difference between `JoinColumn` and `mappedBy` you can take a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11939045/3669624).

## EDIT:

For the mapping between `SubjectPlace` and `PersonSubjectPlace`:

**In your SubjectPlace class:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="subjectPlace")
private List<PersonSubjectPlace> personsubjectPlaces;
```

**In your PersonSubjectPlace class:**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="SPID") //Specify the primary key of SubjectPerson
private SubjectPlace subjectPlace;
```

**Note:**

The best approach to map those classes is to use `@JoinTable` between  `Person` and `SubjectPlace`, take a look at [**this @JoinTable example**](http://fruzenshtein.com/hibernate-join-table-intermediary/), because `PersonSubjectPlace` is pratically an asociation-entity between `Person` and `SubjectPlace`.

Comment: Thanks for links to additional info.
I've update question with Image of DB diagram. Unfortunately I can't see how to implement you answer, yet. Maybe I stare in wrong direction...

Comment: In that case yopu should place the second part of the code in my answer in the `PersonSubjectPlace` class instead of `SubjectPlace`.

Comment: Yep, this is woks for Person and PersonSubjectPlace. But it fails when PersonSubjectPlace links with SubjectPlace. It can't link this FK with PK, and shows me this error, what in question

Comment: @miroque Use the same type of mapping used with `Person` and `PersoSubjectPlace`, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: unfortunatley it didn't work also. In i-net I've found some [similar problem](http://www.coderbag.com/NHibernate/Foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-the-referenced-primary-key) but author done his task, but in 2011 year...

Comment: The best approach for those classes is to use `@JoinTable` between  `Person` and `SubjectPlace`, take a look at [**this @JoinTable example**](http://fruzenshtein.com/hibernate-join-table-intermediary/).

Comment: thanks for another link, yep i've done my code to work, i don't know how, but it helped with `@JoinTable` principals... i give my code after time. maybe it's not optimal but...

Comment: @miroque was this answer helpful for you? if so please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `@Joincolumn` annotation and add `mappedBy` variable to `@OneToMany` annotation.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "spid")
```

You should have a variable in `SubjectPlace` that has a `Person` where you should put `@JoinColumn` annotation

Comment: No, that's not worked.And I didn't understand about "variable in SubjectPlace that has a Person"