# How to get joined data on inversed entity with @ManyToOne relation?

Tags: java, jpa

I am working on my school project and kind of replicating Stack Exchange site (project purpose only)

There is a table called *Posts* which might be a *Question* same as an *Answer*, based on *PostTypeId*. When it is a *Question*, it's column called *AcceptedAnswerId* is populated. However, there is no column listing all *Answers* for that *Question*.

The only relation between the *Question* and it's *Answers* is a column *ParentId* in the *Answers*. Meaning `@ManyToOne`

Now I need to get all *Answers* per that *Question*.

Any idea whether such thing is even possible?

So far, I've got something like this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ParentId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
public Post getParentPost(){
    return parentPost;
}

public void setParentPost(Post parentPost) {
    this.parentPost = parentPost;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to also map the other end  like this :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ParentPost")
public List<Post> getChildPosts();
```

see also  [JPA JoinColumn vs mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)

Comment: Thank you, but I am having an error on the FetchType.Lazy... when I change it to Eager it makes some kind of infinite loop result. Like a recursive retrieval...

Comment: try @OneToMany( mappedBy = "parentPost") - i have here no java ee environment to test :(

Comment: I just had to add  @JsonIgnore, into one of the fields which was causing the infinite circulation-like effect. But basically your answer is correct :)