# How to store entities in Spring Data JPA or hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have these 2 `entities` , which are related to each other using `OnetoMany` Mapping.

Entity:

```
@Table(name = "table_A")
public class UserSum{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    private String order_id;
    private Date order_date;
    @Column(name="email_address")
    private String emailAddress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userOrderID",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<OrderSummary> orderSummary;
        // Getter and Setters

    }


     @Entity
     @Table(name = "table_B")
     public class AlphaSumm {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
        private Long id;
        @Column(name="user_orders_id",nullable = true)
        private Long userSumID; 
        @Column(name="total_price")
        private String  totalPrice;
            // Getter and setters

        }
```

Requirement: i want to save the UserSum and AphaSum.

Problems:

i am trying something like this

```
private void save(Order order){
    UserSum usersum = new UserSum();
    usersum.setOrder_id(order.getOrder_id());
    usersum.setOrderSummary(getAllOrdersSummary(order,userOrders));
    userOrdersRepository.save(userOrders);
}

private OrderSummary processOrderSummary(Item item,UserOrders userOrders){
    OrderSummary orderSummary= new OrderSummary();

    // Some code here  
    orderSummary.setUserOrderID(userOrders.getId());  
    return orderSummary;
    }
```

Note: UserOrder is the entity

but i get **userOrderID** null in db.

**My understanding is :**
I am explicitly setting id here
**`orderSummary.setUserOrderID(userOrders.getId());`**

but its null here because JPA/Hibernate will create the id once it saves the data so how can i map them. One solution i have thought of is  something like this

```
userOrders = userOrdersRepository.save(userOrders);  // to get the id and then perform rest of the operation.
userOrders.setOrderSummary(getAllOrdersSummary(order,userOrders));
userOrdersRepository.save(userOrders);
```

but am pretty sure this is not the right way to go. 
Please provide me your inputs and if something is missing from my side then please let me know.

**Updated**

```
private List<OrderSummary> getAllOrdersSummary(Order order,UserOrders userOrders ){
    List<OrderSummary> orderSummary=new ArrayList<OrderSummary>();
    //some logic
    orderSummary.add(processOrderSummary(item,userOrders));
    return orderSummary;
}

private OrderSum processOrderSum(Item item,UserSum usersum){
    OrderSum orderSum= new OrderSum();
    orderSum.setOrderItems(item.getName());
    orderSum.setTotalPrice(NumberFormating.currencyFormat(item.getPrice()));
    orderSum.setQuantity(NumberFormating.numberFormat(item.getQty()));
    orderSum.setUserOrderID(usersum.getId()); 

    return orderSum
```

Comment: can you show the code of `getAllOrdersSummary(order,userOrders)` please. And your Order class/entity

Comment: @Patrick: please see updated code.   Order class is just a model, it is picking data from xml (nothing special about order)

Comment: `@Column(name="user_orders_id",nullable = true) private Long userOrderID;` in OrderSummary is the Key of UserOrders right?

Comment: mappedBy has to point to the other side of BIDIRECTIONAL relation. It doesn't in your classes, so either remove it or put a ManyToOne at the other side. A "Long" is not a relation in O-O.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `OrderSummary` Entity like this:

```
@Table(name = "table_B")
public class OrderSummary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private UserOrders userOrders;  

    @Column(name="total_price")
    private String  totalPrice;

}
```

Just give a try.

And please have a look here: [pa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)