# Hibernate extra lazy not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities: 
Entry and Comment. One entry has n comments.
I want to add extra lazy loading in my Entry for Comments. My entities looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entries")
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public boolean containsComment(int commentId) {
        return comments.contains(commentId);
    }

    public Comment getComment(int commentId) {
        return comments.get(commentId);
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="comments")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Entry entry;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Entry getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(Entry entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }
}
```

I wrote a test to test the association mapping:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testContainsComment() {
    /* I inserted already an entry and a comment for the entry into the database */
    Entry entry = entryDao.getById(1);
    boolean containsComment = entry.containsComment(1); // -> Here I get the following exception: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public int com.mypackage.Comment.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.mypackage.Comment#id] : 1
    Assert.assertTrue(containsComment);
}
```

Why I get the following exception?

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public int com.mypackage.Comment.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.mypackage.Comment#id] : 1
```

What did I missed?

**Additional Info**
I should mention that I can access the comments collection with the getComments() method. The size() on the comments collection works too. The single problem is the contains() method. Note that I pass the commentId as parameter to the containsComment()-method. Can / Should I pass something else?

The funny thing is that hibernate logs the right query for the contains method.

```
Hibernate: select 1 from comments where entry_id =? and id =?
```

Comment: What exactly is your question asking? You show your code, and you show the output, but you never specifically state where the problem is.

Comment: The exception is the problem :)

Comment: I should mention that I can access the comments collection with the getComments() method. The size() on the comments collection works too. The single problem is the contains() method. Note that I pass the commentId as parameter to the containsComment()-method. Can / Should I pass something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the method `comments.contains()` in the incorrect way.

```
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

`comments` is a `List` of `Comment`, so you need to pass a `Comment` to the `contains()` method

`comments.contains(new Comment(1))`

Obviously, this code find nothing, because of, `contains()` uses equals (by reference, in this case) to check equality of objects. You can override `equals()` and `hashCode()` of `Comment` to get a valid behavior.

Or you can use a loop and check id equality element by element, or use a temporary set with ids, if you need to check a lot of comments, or query a database for checking particular `Comment` id.

Answer (score 1):

add  setter your `Entry.class` property `comments`  setter not added

add this in `Entry.class`

```
public List<Comment> setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
```

**Edit**
refactor `containsComment` method like this

```
public boolean containsComment(int commentId) {

       for(Comment comment : getComments()){
          if(comment.getId() == commentId){
             return true;
          } }       
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. Did it help in your case? Can you show me some code?

Comment: I should mention that I can access the comments collection with the getComments() method. The size() on the comments collection works too. The single problem is the contains() method. Note that I pass the commentId as parameter to the containsComment()-method. Can / Should I pass something else?

Comment: It is incorrect. `getComments()` returns a `List`, it doesn't have `getId()` method!

Comment: I would take this answer a step further by refactoring the `containsComment()` method out of the entity into a separate class to keep things easy to test.

Comment: @Saheed yes ,not good choice in entity class use logic, I was carrying this method into a class with private access

Comment: You can use entity based logic in the entity. Otherwise the entities would be simple data objects without responsibility.

Comment: @user3481997 yes you can use it's possible but not good choice for single responsibility principle

Answer (score 0):

try this:

on Comment class, after *@ManyToOne*, specify a **@JoinColumn** like:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
```

Check also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby).

Comment: No, still got the same exception.

Comment: I should mention that I can access the comments collection with the getComments() method. The size() on the comments collection works too. The single problem is the contains() method. Note that I pass the commentId as parameter to the containsComment()-method. Can / Should I pass something else?

Comment: if `mappedBy` is used, Hibernate uses implicitly `@JoinColumn`. But it is a good practice to specify `@JoinColumn` explicity.