# what is @JoinColumn and how it is used in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have been reading a lot about @JoinColumn but I still don't get the idea behind it.

Patient Table

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
patient_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(patient_id));
```

Vehicle Table

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles (
patient_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
vehicle_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
vehicle_manufacturer VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_id),
CONSTRAINT patienthasmanyvehicle FOREIGN KEY(patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id));
```

Patient Class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private Collection<Vehicle> patientVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

Vehicle Class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="patient_id")
private Patient patient;
```

I'm confused on how the Vehicle class part, what is the relationship between

```
Vehicle Class ---- Entity
@JoinColumn(name="patient_id") ---- annotation
private Patient patient ----field
```

Does it say; The **Vehicle Entity** has a **Foreign Key** to **Patient entity** named **patient_id**. 
Add the **patient_id** as a column in the **Vehicle Entity table**

Do the name parameter of the JoinColumn should always be a **Foreign Key or Primary Key?**

I have been reading this but I'm still confuse.
[JPA JoinColumn vs mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)

Answer (score 78):

**A unidirectional association via a join table**

```
@Entity
class Patient {

    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

}

@Entity
class Vehicle {

}
```

**A bidirectional association via a join table**

```
@Entity
class Patient {

    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

}

@Entity
class Vehicle {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Patient patient;

}
```

**A unidirectional association via a foreign key**

```
@Entity
class Patient {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

}

@Entity
class Vehicle {

}
```

**A bidirectional association via a foreign key**

```
@Entity
class Patient {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

}

@Entity
class Vehicle {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Patient patient;

}
```

We don't need to use `@JoinColumn` on the `Vehicle` side, Hibernate assumes
it by default. Sometimes I use it just to stress it out (another case, when we want to specify a join column name).

```java
    @Entity
    class Vehicle {
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn
        private Patient patient;
    
    }
```

**A bidirectional association via a foreign key with a foreign column name specification**

```
@Entity
class Patient {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

}

@Entity
class Vehicle {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="patient_id")
    private Patient patient;

}
```

This is the basic starting point of using `@JoinColumn`.

To verify that the foreign key(`patient_id` in the `Vehicle` table) is really mapped in the patients table you can use `@JoinColumn(nullable = false)`

```
@Entity
class Vehicle {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="patient_id", nullable = false)
    private Patient patient

}
```

Comment: isn't there a implicit `@JoinColum` when you specify `@OneToMany`? I mean are An association via a join table, A unidirectional association via a foreign key more different than just a default coulmn name and manual coulmn name?

Comment: @sql_dummy `@JoinColumn` is not used for a join table. I don't understand  the second question. For the unidirectional and bidirectional associations you will have the same database schema.

Comment: I mean is `@JoinColumn` not specified implicitly when I specify @OneToMany? I got this doubt because going through `Debug` file I see the feild has similar `binding` weather I explicitly use `@JoinColumn`  or not. (I guess the answer to my question is most probably "no", but why is similar `binding`)

Comment: can you please answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679668/hibernate-why-is-binding-for-a-field-similar-weather-explicit-joincolum-annota)

Comment: @v.ladynev I have two Entity **Publisher** and  **Book** and both of them have bidirectional association but the `@JoinColumn` is specified on `@OneToMany` side. What type of relation is this can you please answer Link: https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring5webapp/tree/publisher-relationships/src/main/java/guru/springframework/spring5webapp/domain

Comment: @Akki I think that this is a bidirectional association. Better to use `mappedBy` in such situations.

Comment: This answer is missing the table in which the join column will be found, answer given by [Yogesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59700281/4982691)

Comment: With the last case, can use the @ManyToOne unidirectional with JoinColumn ?

Comment: @BeliliF yes. Just add `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` and `@JoinColumn(name = "fk_some_column")`

Comment: @v.ladynev is it mandatory to set "fetch = FetchType.LAZY" for this to work

Comment: @BeliliF No. But my advice is to always do that.

Comment: Amazing response here.  Wondering what the benefit of bidirectional is with unidirectional though

Comment: @Amir For `OneToMany` always use bidirectional. You will not to load all the list just to delete an item.

Comment: wouldn't the second example create two distinct unidirectional associations?

Comment: @MehdiCharife It depends on `bidirectional` definition. For example, it can be `bidirectional` because of when we add a `Vehicle` to a `Patient`, we need to set the `Patient` to  the`Vehicle`.

Comment: @v.ladynev That's not what bidirectional means.

Answer (score 9):

The join column is declared with the @JoinColumn annotation which looks like the @Column annotation. It has one more parameters named referencedColumnName. This parameter declares the column in the targeted entity that will be used to the join.

In a bidirectional relationship, one of the sides (and only one) has to be the owner: the owner is responsible for the association column(s) update. To declare a side as not responsible for the relationship, the attribute mappedBy is used. mappedBy refers to the property name of the association on the owner side.

Here is Sample code :

```
EntityOne : 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEST_ID")
    private EntityTwo entityTwo;

EntityTwo : 
      // bi-directional many-to-one association to EntityOne Here TEST_ID is the Primary key
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityTwo")
    private List<EntityOne> entityOne;
```

Comment: How to replace the @JoinColumn(name = "TEST_ID") in hbm mapping file??

Answer (score 5):

Vehicle Class ---- Entity
`@JoinColumn(name="patient_id")` ---- annotation
private Patient patient ----field

Above code will generate a column `patient_id` (a foreign key) in Vehicle class which will point to Patient Class primary key.

`MappedBy` - This attribute tells us that this relation will be managed by Vehicle class. Example. If we insert a vehicle, then two SQL will be injected if cascadetype is all/save. 1st SQL will inject details in Patient table and 2nd SQL will inject vehicle details in vehicle table with patient_id column of Vehicle column pointing to Patient tuple inserted.

Comment: but why is that the **patient_id (generated column which is a FK)** in the **Vehicle Table** doesn't have any value when I run my code?

Comment: @zenlloyd For a unidirectional association It is impossible. For a bidirectional It is normal.

Comment: is there a way to verify that the foreign key(patient_id in Vehicle table) is really mapped in the patients table?

Comment: @zenlloyd. To have patient object mapped properly, you need to make sure that you have patient attribute set in vehicle object. If this value is not set, then patient_id will be injected with null value.

Answer (score 1):

The table in which join column will be found depends upon context.

- If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the source entity or embeddable.
- If the join is for a unidirectional OneToMany mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key is in the table of the target entity.
- If the join is for a ManyToMany mapping or for a OneToOne or bidirectional ManyToOne/OneToMany mapping using a join table, the foreign key is in a join table.
- If the join is for an element collection, the foreign key is in a collection table.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that the `patient_id` (generated column which is a FK) in the
>   Vehicle Table doesn't have any value when I run my code?

All `@JoinColumn` does is to specify a column for joining an entity association or element collection. Since you have made `@JoinColumn` associated with Patient class object, that's why foreign key is created on Patient table.

For more please refer https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html

Comment: This statement: "Since you have made @JoinColumn associated with Patient class object, that's why foreign key is created on Patient table." is NOT correct. This is the reason: **"If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the source entity or embeddable."**