# What is a correct way of designing REST API's for SpringBoot

Tags: spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, spring-restdocs

As I know about designing of REST-API's in SpringBoot we will design API's for User like

1. > For ADD User = **/v1/users** *(Add a single object into a user collection)*
2. > For GET/UPDATE/DELETE user = **/v1/users/{userId}** (for get/update/delete
   >   a single object from users collection)

Now We also design an API's for User Address like

1. > For Add Address = **/v1/users/{userId}/addresses** *(Add a single object
   >       into addresses of user followed by userId)*
2. > For GET/UPDATE/DELETE = **/v1/users/{userId}/addresses/{addressId}**
   >       *(get/update /delete of address from addresses for a user of given
   >       userId)*

So, I have created API's like this but for add/get/update/delete I can direct addresses into Address table via RestController -> Services -> Repository -> DB

Now for Address CRUD I'm never used {userId} which is provided in API

Sample for Add/Update address

```
@Override
public Address addAddress(Address address) {

    address = addressRepository.save(address);
    return address;
}
```

Is there I'm doing something wrong in code or my concept about rest is not cleared.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think first you should come up with the structure of relationship between user and address.
2. Like **ADDRESS CANT EXISTS WITHOUT USER**  and **USER CAN HAVE MANY ADDRESSES** or **CAN HAVE ONLY ONE ADDRESS**  that is basically the cardinality of the relationship.
   [See the accepted anwer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065484/one-to-many-relationship-in-spring-data-jpa)
3. Once that done and you come up with the **CASCADE TYPE** and **USE THE HELPER** method persist the parent along with child.
   [Here is the good example.](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)
   Will try to upload code for your example.
   Let me know of this:)

**EDIT:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private Long id;

    private String userName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        addresses.add(address);
        address.setUser(this);
    }

    public void removeAddress(Address address) {
        address.setUser(null);
        this.addresses.remove(address);
    }

}
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {
    private Long id;

    private String address;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
public class Service 
{
   @PostMapping(value="/saveAddressForUser")
   public void saveAddressForUser(@RequestBody AddressForUser address)
   {
       User user=getUserFromDatabase(userId);
       user.addAddress(address);
       Repository.persist(user);//it will also persist address as cascade type is all.
   }
}
```