# How can I do the multiply relations in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, annotations, mapping

everyone! Sorry but I need some help. My db is [looking this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Scg.png), I try to do same throught the Hibernate in Java.

But I don`t understand how I need to annoted this relations with so many different tables. 
It`s a part of my Abiturient table.

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "abiturient",
            uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})

public class Abiturient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
    @ManyToOne
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Date data_narodjennya;

    @Column
    private Integer city_village;
```

It`s a part of my nomer_telefonu table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nomer_telefonu")
public class NomerTelefonu {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "nomer_tel_id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long nomer_tel_id;

    @Column(name = "nomer")
    private String nomer;

    @Column(name = "id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Abiturient> id;
```

I don`t think that all there is right, `cos every time I try to solve problem I get an error and need other type.

Comment: In `NomerTelefonu` the `@Column` is suspicious in conjunction with `@OneToMany`. There should be a `@JoinColumn`. Also the `@ManyToOne` in `Abiturient` seems wrong. I would try to use netbeans to creates entities from DB.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj Thanks a lot! Will wait. What type of relations I should use in `Abiturient`?  And how to write it without an error in code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@OneToMany` bidirectional relation.

```
@Entity
public class Abiturient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "abiturent")
    private List<NomerTelefonu> phones = Lists.newArrayList();

} 

@Entity
public class NomerTelefonu{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "nomer_tel_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Abiturient abiturent;

}
```

`Lists.newArrayList()` from guava. This is working mapping. Always use the simplest version to experiment.

[what is @JoinColumn and how it is used in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542208/what-is-joincolumn-and-how-it-is-used-in-hibernate/37542849#37542849)

You can use this project to play with mappings in the unit tests:

https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-experimental

Comment: Thank you!!! Haha, read this link before your answer) But the id in `NomerTelefonu` is the`nomer_tel_id`, no an `id`. Why do I need to create other variable, it is depends on the id or not? how will it know how to  associate them?     Don\`t catch the thing about _Lists.newArrayList() from guava. This is working mapping._   Will be really happy, if you answer me.

Comment: @ziki That was just an example. I updated the id column name. "Why do I need to create other variable" Did you ask about an `id`?

Comment: Thanks. No, in general my question is " Why do  I need an other variable?" and How is it work?

Comment: I mean other variables as this   `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "abiturent")
    private List<NomerTelefonu> phones = Lists.newArrayList();`  and  ` @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Abiturient abiturent;`

Comment: @ziki Hibernate doesn't work with ids. It works with classes (objects) like `Abiturient`.  You can use ids, but it will be much complex. For example, you can't use HQL join with ids using Hibernate version prior 5.10. Also Hibernate can generate a database schema, if classes are used.