# How to use the Hibernate Join Column?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes and relations between them.  Can`t understand where the problem is. I write code in the next way.

```
 public class Abiturient {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "prizv_id")
        private Prisvishche abiturients_pr;
```

And mapped one:

```
public class Prisvishche {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private BigInteger prizv_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prizv_id")
    private List<Abiturient> abiturients = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: did you read this linkn:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542208/what-is-joincolumn-and-how-it-is-used-in-hibernate

Comment: Yes, I did, but really understanding is coming only when you improve your own error for the 3d time) thanx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot point to a database column in a `mappedBy`.
You have to point to an entity field that is the owning side of the relationship and that is:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "prizv_id")
 private Prisvishche abiturients_pr;
```

So your owned side should be:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "abiturients_pr")
private List<Abiturient> abiturients = new ArrayList();
```