# Hibernate: Why is binding for a field similar weather explicit @JoinColum annotation is used or not?

Tags: hibernate, orm, annotations, associations, hibernate-mapping

Is `@JoinColum` implicitly specified when we use any association type annotation like `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, etc.

Here is snippet from `Student` entity in association with `Laptop` entity

Case 1) Without using explicit @JoinColum

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Laptop> laptops=new ArrayList<Laptop>();
```

Case 2) Using explicit `@JoinColum`

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn
private List<Laptop> laptops=new ArrayList<Laptop>();
```

When I check `DEBUG` both cases have "almost" similar `Binding`, i.e something like below.

1) So could I assume `@JoinColum` is implicitly specified when `@OneToMany`is specified? But wait I also noticed Hibernate is trying to refer to some totally strange table 'student_laptops' which I have not created anywhere (probably a join table).

So can someone describe whats exactly the flow going here?

Debug:  `private List<Laptop> laptops=new ArrayList<Laptop>();`

```
//You can totally ignore this. Just specifying for any reference.

DEBUG - Binding column: Ejb3JoinColumn{logicalColumnName='null', referencedColumn='null', mappedBy=''}
DEBUG - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(STUDENT), mappingColumn=laptops, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
DEBUG - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(STUDENT), mappingColumn=null, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
DEBUG - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(STUDENT), mappingColumn=element, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
DEBUG - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(STUDENT), mappingColumn=laptops_KEY, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
DEBUG - Binding column: Ejb3JoinColumn{logicalColumnName='laptops_KEY', referencedColumn='null', mappedBy='null'}
DEBUG - Binding column: Ejb3JoinColumn{logicalColumnName='null', referencedColumn='null', mappedBy=''}
DEBUG - Binding column: Ejb3JoinColumn{logicalColumnName='null', referencedColumn='null', mappedBy=''}
DEBUG - Collection role: com.infiniteskills.data.entities.Student.laptops
DEBUG - Building property laptops
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is @JoinColum implicitly specified when we use any association type annotation like @OneToOne, @OneToMany, etc.

The answer is: **NO**. Except the case when `mappedBy` is used.

When you specify `@JoinColumn` or `mappedBy` (even without `@JoinColumn`) Hibernate implies that you want to use an association via a foreign key (without a join table).

When you don't specify `@JoinColumn` Hibernate uses a join table and creates it for you — `student_laptops` in your case.

You can add a `@JoinTable` annotation to stress the fact that you are using a jon table.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable
private List<Laptop> laptops = new ArrayList<Laptop>();
```

Comment: Also I am confused that why is the `Binding` information at `Debug` file similar for this field with or without explicit @JoinColumn

Comment: @sql_dummy You should check not the Binding information, but generated SQL. You need to enable SQL logs for that and generate the schema DDL using `Configuration#generateSchemaCreationScript()`. Also, if you work on  a test project you can just recreate the schema (with losing all the data of course).

Comment: Q2: And also why is that `@JoinColumn` not required in `@OneToOne` if table corresponding source entity has a column has column `laptop_Laptop_Id` (ie field name+_+pk of reffered table).

Comment: Q3: But isn.t that  Binding information that gives the complete information of annotations, like what are the fields exactly mapped to.

Comment: @sql_dummy Probably it is default behaviour for  `@OneToOne`. _Binding information that gives the complete information of annotations_ — probably no, I have never checked this