# Hibernate MappingException: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have this entity, called FatRabbitCarrot:

```
@Entity
public class FatRabbitCarrot {
    private Long id;
    private FatRabbit fatRabbit;
    private Carrot carrot;

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fatRabbit_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_FatRabbitCarrot_fatRabbit"))
public FatRabbit getFatRabbit() {
    return fatRabbit;
}

public void setFatRabbit(FatRabbit fatRabbit) {
    this.fatRabbit = fatRabbit;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "carrot_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_FatRabbitCarrot_carrot"))
public Carrot getCarrot() {
    return carrot;
}

public void setCarrot(Carrot carrot) {
    this.carrot = carrot;
}
}
```

And it works. Now the above class had field names replaced, but the structure is the same as in our repository.

Then I tried to add a new entity, that has a foreign key to the class above. Let's call this class NutToffee. FatRabbitCarrot have a OneToMany relationship to this new entity, while the entity itself should have a ManyToOne relationship:

```
@Entity
public class NutToffee {

private Long id;
private String text;
private FatRabbitCarrot fatRabbitCarrot;

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id){
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "text")
public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="fatRabbitCarrot_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_NutToffee_fatRabbitCarrot"))
public FatRabbitCarrot getFatRabbitCarrot() {
    return fatRabbitCarrot;
}

public void setFatRabbitCarrot(FatRabbitCarrot fatRabbitCarrot) {
    this.fatRabbitCarrot = fatRabbitCarrot;
}
}
```

Now this seems like a valid class to me. But it doesn't look like it is. We are using Java 8, Hibernate JPA 2.1, Java EE 7 and gradle to build the artifact we want to deploy. We attempt to deploy it on a Wildfly 10 application server, but we get the following error:

```
[2019-07-08 03:53:45,441] Artifact Gradle : com.solveralynx.wildrunner : fatties.war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"fatties.war#FatUnit\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"fatties.war#FatUnit\": org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_NutToffee_fatRabbitCarrot:NutToffee [fatRabbitCarrot_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (FatRabbitCarrot [fatRabbit_id,carrot_id])
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_NutToffee_fatRabbitCarrot:NutToffee [fatRabbitCarrot_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (FatRabbitCarrot [fatRabbit_id,carrot_id])"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"fatties.war#FatUnit\""],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
```

From my understanding, Hibernate found a composite primary key for FatRabbitCarrot? Even though we never defined one? It seems to pick up a fake primary key, where it uses both foreign keys from entity FatRabbitCarrot.

As for my testing. I am confident this is a Hibernate issue. No matter the database state, I always get this error. I tested with various parameters on the getters, that connect that entities, but no success. If I remove both new OneToMany and ManyToOne connections, the artifact deploys.

Does anyone have any idea why Hibernate is doing this?

Comment: can you add the `Carrot.java` and `FatRabbit.java` in the question?

Comment: Sorry, I went home and couldn't check your response. But your comment made me look through FatRabbit and I did discover FatRabbit having a getter to Carrot via a JoinTable. Removing that allowed me to deploy the code successfuly. Now we are investing what exactly is happening, but at least we know where the issue is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@JoinColumn` annotation incorrectly.

```
@Entity
public class FatRabbitCarrot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OnToMany
    private List<NutToffee> toffies;

}

@Entity
public class NutToffee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fatRabbitCarrot_id")
    private FatRabbitCarrot fatRabbitCarrot;

}
```

This means that you will have association between `FatRabbitCarrot` and `NutToffee` using a join table. An you will have an additional `fatRabbitCarrot_id` column in the `NutToffee` table.

You need to use `mappedBy`

```
    @Entity
    public class FatRabbitCarrot {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @OnToMany(mappedBy = "fatRabbitCarrot")
        private List<NutToffee> toffies;

    }

    @Entity
    public class NutToffee {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "fatRabbitCarrot_id")
        private FatRabbitCarrot fatRabbitCarrot;

    }
```

if you don't need the `@ManyToOne` association, you can use `@JoinColumn` with `@OneToMany` without `mappedBy`

```
    @Entity
    public class FatRabbitCarrot {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @OnToMany
        @JoinColumn(name = "fatRabbitCarrot_id")
        private List<NutToffee> toffies;

    }

    @Entity
    public class NutToffee {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;


    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542849/3405171

Comment: I did try that as well, but didn't help. It seems the issue was with FatRabbit having a JoinTable annotation over FatRabbitCarrot, that loaded all it's Carrot instances. We are still exploring what exactly happens there, but removing that Carrot getter allows the code to deploy.

Comment: @kozeljko Did you try to log SQL that Hibernate uses to generate database schema? Was it correct?

Comment: We are in a bit of a rush and the JoinTable getter isn't used anywhere (no idea why we had it), so we just removed it until we have more time to invest into such a problem.