# How to generate a DTO from a bidirectional table relation in Spring Boot

Tags: sql, json, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Good morning, nice to greet you.

I am new to Spring Boot recently, and I am working with a REST API, which is basically a playlist with songs, basically the REST API should have the following structure. A playlist can have many songs:

```
{
    "name": "Lista 1",
    "description": "Lista de reproduccion 2020 spotify",
    "songs": [
        {
            "title": "Tan Enamorados",
            "artist": "CNCO",
            "album": "Tan Enamorados",
            "year": 2020,
            "playList": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "Hawai",
            "artist": "Maluma",
            "album": "PAPI JUANCHO",
            "year": 2020,
            "playList": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently this is how I have my entities configured

Entity SONGS

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SONGS")
public class Songs{

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "artist")
    private String artist;

    @Column(name = "album")
    private String album;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLAY_LIST_ID")
    private PlayList playList;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return this.artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return this.album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public PlayList getPlayList() {
        return this.playList;
    }

    public void setPlayList(PlayList playList) {
        this.playList = playList;
    }
 
}
```

Entity PLAYLIST

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAY_LIST")
public class PlayList {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

   
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "playList")
    private List<Songs> songs = new ArrayList<>();


    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public List<Songs> getSongs() {
        return this.songs;
    }

    public void setSongs(List<Songs> songs) {
        this.songs = songs;
    }
    
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("playlist")
public class PlayListController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayListService playListService;

    //Get playlist by id with songs belongs that playlist
    
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<PlayList> getPlayListByID(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {

        Optional<PlayList> playList = playListService.getById(id);
        return playList;
     }

     
     @PostMapping("/create")
     public PlayList createPlayList(@RequestBody PlayList playList) {
         return playListService.savePlayList(playList);
     }

}
```

My class PlayListServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class PlayListServiceImpl implements PlayListService {

    @Autowired
    private PlayListRepository playListRepository;

    public Optional <PlayList> getById(Long Id) {
        Optional <PlayList> playList= playListRepository.findById(Id);

        return playList;
    }

    @Override
    public PlayList savePlayList(PlayList playList) {
        return playListRepository.save(playList);
    }
    
}
```

My Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PlayListRepository extends JpaRepository<PlayList, Long> {

    Optional<PlayList> findById(Long Id);
    
}
```

However, I have infinite recursion problem when I try to get a playlist with the get method:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.example.api.songs.entity.PlayList[\"songs\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.api.songs.entity.Songs[\"playList\"]->com.example.api.songs.entity.PlayList[\"songs\"]->org.hibernate.
```

This is due to the playList field found in the Songs entity, when trying to get the playlist with the songs, I get an array that becomes recursive and not the id of the playList, which is what I want to get, the reality is that I get something like this:

[image]

I can solve by applying a JsonIgnore in the field, however this affects me that when I go to save a playlist, I cannot pass the idPlayList field to each song to make sure that each song is saved with its respective idPlayList

I think the best thing would be to build a DTO here that helps me to have the relationship of the 2 tables, however, I don't know how I would do it in a way that allows me, when executing a get from the playList, to obtain only the idPlayList, and when saving power pass the idPlayList in each song that is going to be saved with a playlist, or if there is another way in which I could store a playlist with its songs and have them stored directly, since currently I have to assign by BD to each song the idPlayList

Comment: `public class Songs` has to be `Song`. It is one record, not all the records :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` to the `application.properties` to have `LazyInitializationException`. It will help to build good queries.
   [What is this spring.jpa.open-in-view=true property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549489/what-is-this-spring-jpa-open-in-view-true-property-in-spring-boot)
2. Load `PlayList` with `songs` using JPQL query with `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to fetch songs with the list. So `songs` will be already loaded and `playList` in the song will be lazy. `@EntityGraph` can be used also.

   ```
   select list from PlayList list left join fetch list.songs where list.id = :listId
   ```
3. There is `Hibernate5Module` in Jackson. It allow to omit lazy associations. So Jackson will not touch `playList` in the song.
   [Configure Jackson to omit lazy-loading attributes in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727017/configure-jackson-to-omit-lazy-loading-attributes-in-spring-boot)
4. To build something like a real system. You can add `PlayListResponse`, `SongResponse` classes and map entities to those classes on the service level. Probably you will not need `Hibernate5Module` in this case. But better to experiment with this module too.
5. Enable database logging in `application.properties` with

```
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager=DEBUG

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
```

Check transactions and SQL in the logs carefully. Don't allow Hibernate to produce unnecessary queries.

**How to save the songs with a list**

Add this method to the `PlayList`

```
@Transient
public void addSong(Song song) {
    song.setPlayList(this);
    songs.add(song);
}
```

Add songs to the list using `addSong()` method.

Save `PlayList`. All the songs of a list will be saved by Hibernate with the correct list id, because there is `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in the `@OneToMany`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you give me an example of LEFT JOIN FETCH? if you have it to map the playlist with their songs.

Comment: I have been reading @EntityGraph and it is very good because it allows me to improve the performance in the query, however, I still do not understand how I could load (insert) a playlist with its songs, since the id of the playList is autogenerated and autoincremented by which I do not know how to associate it so that the songs are saved with their id_playList value and thus remain associated to the playList

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test the changes and I'll tell you

Comment: What's up friend? Could you help me with the following question that is related to the Delete method of a song within a PlayList https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527711/delete-object-from-an-entity-with-a-onetomany-relationship-between-both-using-jp