# Delete object from an entity with a OneToMany relationship between both using JPA in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, orm

Good afternoon, I am working with a REST API in which I have a playlist that has many songs, for which I am using JPA and the benefits that allow me to make the relationships between the two. Now, if I want to delete a song already added to the PlayList, I can't do it, I show you my classes below

Class PlayList

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAY_LIST")
public class PlayList {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    //@JsonView(View.Get.class)
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    //@JsonView(View.Get.class)
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    //@JsonView(View.Get.class)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "playList")
    private List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Transient
    public void addSong(Song song) {
        song.setPlayList(this);
        songs.add(song);
    }

    @Transient
    public void removeSong(Song song) {
        songs.remove(song);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public List<Song> getSongs() {
        return this.songs;
    }

    public void setSongs(List<Song> songs) {
        this.songs = songs;
    }
    
}
```

Here I have the methods of adding songs and removing, however, removing is not working for me.

Class Song

```
Entity
@Table(name = "SONG")
public class Song{

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    //@JsonView(View.Create.class)
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    //@JsonView(View.Create.class)
    @Column(name = "artist")
    private String artist;

    //@JsonView(View.Create.class)
    @Column(name = "album")
    private String album;

    //@JsonView(View.Create.class)
    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;

    /* 

    Fetch: Esta propiedad se utiliza para determinar cómo debe ser cargada la entidad.
    LAZY (perezoso): Indica que la relación solo se cargará cuando la propiedad sea leída por primera vez */
    //@JsonView(View.Get.class)
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLAY_LIST_ID")
    private PlayList playList;


    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return this.artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return this.album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public PlayList getPlayList() {
        return this.playList;
    }

    public void setPlayList(PlayList playList) {
        this.playList = playList;
    }
    
}
```

My class Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("playlist")
public class PlayListController {

   @Autowired
   private PlayListService playListService;

   @Autowired
   private SongRepository songRepository;


   // Get playlist by id with songs belongs that playlist

   @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
   public Optional<PlayList> getPlayListByID(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {

      Optional<PlayList> playList = playListService.getById(id);
      return playList;
   }

   @PostMapping("/create")
   public PlayList createPlayList(@RequestBody PlayListDTO playListDTO) {

      PlayList playList = new PlayList();

      playList.setName(playListDTO.getName());
      playList.setDescription(playListDTO.getDescription());
      playList.setSongs(new ArrayList<>());

      for (int x=0; x<playListDTO.getSongs().size(); x++) {

         Song songs=new Song();
         songs.setTitle(playListDTO.getSongs().get(x).getTitle());
         songs.setArtist(playListDTO.getSongs().get(x).getArtist());
         songs.setAlbum(playListDTO.getSongs().get(x).getAlbum());
         songs.setYear(playListDTO.getSongs().get(x).getYear());
         playList.addSong(songs);

      }
        return playListService.savePlayList(playList);
     }
   @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
   public PlayList updatePlayList(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id,@RequestBody Song song){

      PlayList playList = playListService.getById(id).get();
      song.setPlayList(playList);
      playList.getSongs().add(song);
      playListService.savePlayList(playList);
      return playList;
   }
   
   @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
   public PlayList deletePlayList(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id,@RequestBody Song song){
      PlayList playList =playListService.getById(id).get();
      System.out.println(playList.getSongs());
      playList.removeSong(song);
      System.out.println(playList.getSongs());
      return playList;
   }

}
```

So I am storing the Playlist with its songs, method POST

```
{
    "name": "Lista 1",
    "description": "Lista de reproduccion 2020 spotify",
    "songs": [
        {
            "title": "Tan Enamorados",
            "artist": "CNCO",
            "album": "Tan Enamorados",
            "year": 2020
        },
        {
            "title": "Hawai",
            "artist": "Maluma",
            "album": "PAPI JUANCHO",
            "year": 2020
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, to eliminate I am passing the id of the PlayList and the Request of the song (object without the id of the song that is automatically created in BD), however, I cannot eliminate the song from the PlayList, and at the logs level it returns this doing a print in console

Example, I want to delete the following song:

[image]

however it is not removed and it returns the same list to me

Am I missing something to be able to delete a song without having to delete the playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a very good idea to remove a song using all the songs list in the `PlayList`.
There is not a join table for `@OneToMany` association. So we can delete a song much simpler, using `SONG` table (this is the main reason why a join table for `@OneToMany` is not convienent).

You need a song id for that and you need to use `CrudRepository.deleteById()` method.
You can use the full combination (title, artist, album, year) for that, but much simpler to add a song id to JSON.

Better to use this endpoint URL to delete a song

`/{playListId}/songs/{songId}`

You don't need `delete` part in the URL, you already use DELETE HTTP method.

**Why your code doesn't work**

1. Incorrect using delete method from the list

```
@Transient
public void removeSong(Song song) {
    songs.remove(song);
}
```

`songs.remove()` can't find `song` in the list, `List.remove()` finds a song by a reference. It needs to have an open persistent context and get a song from it to have an ability to find it in the list.

2. Not using a transaction (opened persistent context) to let Hibernate know that a song was deleted and Hibernate has to update the database.

So a valid scenario

```
start @Transactional
  Spring starts a database transaction
  Spring opens a persistent context
  load PlayList
  load a song from the database (using id or other song attributes)
  delete a song from PlayList songs (or delete a song from PlayList songs using id)
end @Transactional
    
Hibernate flushes changes and delete a song in the database
persistent context is closed
database transaction is committed
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I undestarnd that I the good way to delete a song is delete through  object Song and method http delete,  sending the song id. 

What are the disadvantages of using OneToMany?

Comment: I'm curious how the Spotify playlist works in real life through relationships, that's what I was trying to do with this

Comment: @CesarJusto if you want to delete a song using `@OneToMany` collection, you have to load all the songs from the database, delete one from the collection and save a play list with the songs. Hibernate will delete a record and doesn't update everything of course.

Comment: @CesarJusto Working with songs collection can be useful, if a user changes a few elements of the collection, so you can use `merge()` method to add or delete multiple elements.

Comment: To delete a song with @OneToMay, I delete a song with the entity song and the remove method and then save the list again with the same id?, Or as is the procedure in that case, since I tried to do it using the remove function in the song entity and save again through the save function but it still did not return the updated list, or I do not know if it created a new list

Comment: In fact, I used the same sense as in the deletePlayList method, adding to save the PlayList at the end, but nothing happened.

Comment: @CesarJusto Enable logging for the Hibernate and check SQL statements in the log. If you delete an item from the list inside in transaction (with opened persistent context), you don't need to call the `save()` method. Hibernate will update database cause of dirty checking (I prefer to call save explicit, but it is not a common approach).

Comment: Thanks. You can put an example of what you are telling me or an example in the web

Comment: @CesarJusto https://learnjava.co.in/automatic-dirty-checking-in-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

```json
{
    "name": "Lista 1",
    "description": "Lista de reproduccion 2020 spotify",
    "songs": [
        {
            "title": "Tan Enamorados",
            "artist": "CNCO",
            "album": "Tan Enamorados",
            "year": 2020
        },
        {
            "title": "Hawai",
            "artist": "Maluma",
            "album": "PAPI JUANCHO",
            "year": 2020
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).