# foreign key coming as null in springboot jpa one to many

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, persistence, hibernate-mapping

> When I am saving the entity  the foreign key in the child table is
> coming as null
>
> the parent class is Appointment   consisting child class slotdetails mapped
> with one to many relationships

```
package com.inskade.inkflow.appoinments;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity()
@Table(name = "appoinment_detail")

public class Appointment  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updatedAt;


    
    private String userId;
    private LocalDate appointmentDate;

    
      @OneToMany(
                mappedBy = "appoinment",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true
            )
            private List<SlotDetails> slotDetails = new ArrayList<>();
      
        public void addSlots(SlotDetails slot) {
            slotDetails.add(slot);
            slot.setAppoinment(this);
        }
     
        public void removeSlot(SlotDetails slot) {
            slotDetails.remove(slot);
            slot.setAppoinment(null);
        }
     
    }
```

> The child class is Slotdetails  having many to one relationship with parent Appoinment

```
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Data
@Entity
public class SlotDetails {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long slotId;
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     
        private Appoinment appoinment;
     private Time appointmentStartTime;
        private Time appointmentEndTime;
    private String bookingStatus
    private String bookedClientId;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SlotDetails )) return false;
        return slotId != null && slotId.equals(((SlotDetails) o).getSlotId());
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

}
```

> the repository

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AppoinmentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Appoinment, Long> {


    List<Appoinment> findAllByAppointmentDateBetween(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);

}
```

> The table Information of the child shows

```
FOREIGN KEY (`appoinment_id`) REFERENCES `appoinment_detail` (`id`)
```

> here the appoinment_id in the child table is coming as null when I
> call appoinmentRepository.save, in the parent table everything is fine
>
> please help

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified [@JoinColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542849/13866126) for `appointment` in `SlotDetails`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="appoinment_id", nullable = false)
private Appoinment appoinment;
```

Comment: tried that but not working, I followed this blog  
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
in this I tried to do Bidirectional @OneToMany  given there

Comment: That's seems weird. Can you paste the code where you build the entity and call save?

Comment: here  are the classes  - https://github.com/spb722/testing