# Unexpected behavior when using @JoinColumn for ONE-TO-MANY association [SpringBoot]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I was practicing One-to-many association between two entities that are - **Book** and **Library** 
I m using SpringBoot 2 alongside Spring-data-jpa and H2 database. 
My aim was to establish a unidirectional mapping in such a way that by using `@OneToMany annotation` within Library entity, so that library table maintains a join table entry. On the other hand, I have used `@ManyToOne annotation` within Book Entity which maintains a column for foreign key (library_Id).

***Scenario 1 :***
Under this scenario when I m not using @JoinColumn annotation along with `@OneToMany` annotated field within Library Entity everything works as expected i.e. a join table is being maintained by the library table whereas a foreign key is stored in book table. Below I have shared the code as well as outputs screenshots for this scenario :

Book.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_table")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id ;
    private String title ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "library_id")
    private Library library ;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Library getLibrary() {
        return library;
    }

    public void setLibrary(Library library) {
        this.library = library;
    }
}
```

Library.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lib_table")
public class Library {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id ;

    private String libname ;
    @OneToMany
    private List <Book> books = new ArrayList<>() ;

    public Library() {
    }

    public Library(String libname) {
        this.libname = libname;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLibname() {
        return libname;
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
}
```

Main Method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(OneToManyApplication.class, args);
        BookRepo bookrepo = context.getBean(BookRepo.class) ;
        LibRepo libRepo = context.getBean(LibRepo.class) ;

        Library lib1 = new Library("MIT Library") ;
        Library lib2 = new Library("Vivekanand Library") ;
        libRepo.save(lib1) ;
        libRepo.save(lib2) ;

        Book book1 = new Book("Science" ) ;
        Book book2 = new Book("Dharma" );
        Book book3 = new Book("Philosophy") ;

        book1.setLibrary(lib1);
        book2.setLibrary(lib2);
        book3.setLibrary(lib1);

        bookrepo.save(book1) ;
        bookrepo.save(book2) ;
        bookrepo.save(book3) ;

        List<Book> booklist1 = Arrays.asList(book1, book3) ;
        List<Book> booklist2 = Arrays.asList(book2) ;

        lib1.setBooks(booklist1);
        lib2.setBooks(booklist2);
        libRepo.save(lib1) ;
        libRepo.save(lib2) ;

    }
```

**Output :** 
[image]

***Scenario 2 :***
Under this scenario, I tried using @JoinColumn annotation along with @OneToMany annotated field within Library Entity. This breaks the expected behavior since now there is no join table being maintained as well as one more column is introduced in book table. Below I have shared the modified code as well as outputs screenshots for this scenario :

Library.java (modified)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lib_table")
public class Library {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id ;

    private String libname ;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "booklist_id")              // only modified line
    private List <Book> books = new ArrayList<>() ;

    public Library() {
    }

    public Library(String libname) {
        this.libname = libname;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLibname() {
        return libname;
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
}
```

**Output :** 
[image]

**Kindly help me with the underlying logic which makes the join table disappear as well as introduction of one more column in Book table in the second scenario.**

**NOTE :** In both the scenarios, I have used `@JoinColumn annotation` on `private Library library;` field present within Book Entity.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to me, is scenario 1, but add the `mappedBy` attribute on the `@OneToMany`annotation of the `books`collection.

Comment: thnx a lot for responding but I intentionally skipped mappedBy attribute in both scenarios, in order to avoid bidirectional mapping and thus ensure that Library table maintains a join table. This was done with the sole aim of learning the behavior of JoinColumn Annotation in Scenario 2.