# ERROR in Java Spring Boot Jpa Hibernate using database H2. ERROR: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException

Tags: java, sql, spring, database, spring-boot

[**I have other entities that work great for me when making the requests, but others like this (Invoice) in this case that when making the request returns an error could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize, I don't understand what could be the cause, please if anyone could help me I would be very grateful, thanks**]

```
2022-07-21 01:01:20.254  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.facturacion.FacturacionApplication   : Starting FacturacionApplication using Java 17 on DESKTOP-Q22VBSJ with PID 26188 (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\facturacion\target\classes started by Usuario in C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\facturacion)
2022-07-21 01:01:20.255  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.facturacion.FacturacionApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-21 01:01:20.301  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-07-21 01:01:20.301  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-07-21 01:01:20.969  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-21 01:01:21.039  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 61 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-21 01:01:21.371  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4ec1db5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-07-21 01:01:21.464  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2022-07-21 01:01:22.033  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-07-21 01:01:22.047  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-21 01:01:22.047  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-07-21 01:01:22.126  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-21 01:01:22.126  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1825 ms
2022-07-21 01:01:22.155  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-07-21 01:01:22.344  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-07-21 01:01:22.354  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:springcoder'
2022-07-21 01:01:22.563  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-07-21 01:01:22.625  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-07-21 01:01:22.832  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-07-21 01:01:22.944  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-07-21 01:01:23.507  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-07-21 01:01:23.512  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-21 01:01:24.280  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-07-21 01:01:24.316  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-07-21 01:01:24.326  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.facturacion.FacturacionApplication   : Started FacturacionApplication in 4.474 seconds (JVM running for 4.977)
2022-07-21 01:01:24.328  INFO 26188 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.facturacion.FacturacionApplication   : Application started
2022-07-21 01:01:30.380  INFO 26188 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-21 01:01:30.380  INFO 26188 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-21 01:01:30.381  INFO 26188 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-07-21 01:01:30.517 ERROR 26188 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:963) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:427) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy107.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.coderhouse.facturacion.services.Empresa.EmpresaServiceImp.getAllEmpresas(EmpresaServiceImp.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.coderhouse.facturacion.controllers.Empresa.EmpresaController.getEmpresas(EmpresaController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-07-21 01:04:07.752  INFO 26188 --- [       Thread-6] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-21 01:04:07.976  WARN 26188 --- [       Thread-6] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-214]
2022-07-21 01:04:07.977  INFO 26188 --- [       Thread-6] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-07-21 01:04:07.984  INFO 26188 --- [       Thread-6] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

[Factura.java]

```
package com.coderhouse.facturacion.models;


import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "facturas")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Factura implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nro_factura")
    private int nroFactura;

    @Column(name = "fecha_factura")
    private String fecha;

    @Column(name = "id_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @Column(name = "id_empresa")
    private Empresa empresa;

    @Column(name = "id_producto")
    private Producto producto;

    @Column(name = "cantidad")
    private int cantidad;

    @Column(name = "precio_unitario")
    private String precio;

    @Column(name = "precio_total")
    private String precioTotal;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Factura factura = (Factura) o;
        return nroFactura == factura.nroFactura && cantidad == factura.cantidad && id.equals(factura.id) && fecha.equals(factura.fecha) && cliente.equals(factura.cliente) && empresa.equals(factura.empresa) && producto.equals(factura.producto) && precio.equals(factura.precio) && precioTotal.equals(factura.precioTotal);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, nroFactura, fecha, cliente, empresa, producto, cantidad, precio, precioTotal);
    }
}
```

[FacturaRepository.java]

```
package com.coderhouse.facturacion.repositories.Factura;

import com.coderhouse.facturacion.models.Factura;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FacturaRepository extends JpaRepository<Factura, Long> {

}
```

[FacturaService.java]

```
package com.coderhouse.facturacion.services.Factura;

import com.coderhouse.facturacion.models.Factura;

import java.util.List;

public interface FacturaService {

    List<Factura> getAllFacturas();

    Factura getOneFactura(Long id);

    Factura createFactura(Factura factura);

    Factura updateFactura(Factura factura);

    void deleteFactura(Long id);

    void deleteAllFacturas();


}
```

[FacturaServiceImp.java]

```
package com.coderhouse.facturacion.services.Factura;

import com.coderhouse.facturacion.models.Factura;
import com.coderhouse.facturacion.repositories.Factura.FacturaRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class FacturaServiceImp implements FacturaService {

    @Autowired
    FacturaRepository facturaRepository;

    public List<Factura> getAllFacturas() {
        return new ArrayList<>(facturaRepository.findAll());

    }

    public Factura getOneFactura(Long id) {
        return facturaRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public Factura createFactura(Factura factura) {
        return facturaRepository.save(factura);
    }

    public Factura updateFactura(Factura factura) {
        return facturaRepository.save(factura);
    }

    public void deleteFactura(Long id) {
        facturaRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void deleteAllFacturas() {
        facturaRepository.deleteAll();
    }


}
```

[FacturaController.java]

```
package com.coderhouse.facturacion.controllers.Factura;

import com.coderhouse.facturacion.models.Factura;
import com.coderhouse.facturacion.services.Factura.FacturaService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class FacturaController {

    @Autowired
    FacturaService facturaService;

    @GetMapping("/api/facturas")
    public List<Factura> getAllFacturas() {

        return facturaService.getAllFacturas();

    }

    @GetMapping("/api/facturas/{id}")
    public Factura getOneFactura(@PathVariable Long id) {

        return facturaService.getOneFactura(id);

    }

    @PostMapping("/api/facturas")
    public Factura createFactura(@RequestBody Factura factura) {

        return facturaService.createFactura(factura);

    }

    @PutMapping("/api/facturas")
    public Factura updateFactura(@RequestBody Factura factura) {

        return facturaService.updateFactura(factura);


    }

    @DeleteMapping("/api/facturas/{id}")
    public void deleteFactura(@PathVariable Long id) {

        facturaService.deleteFactura(id);


    }


    @DeleteMapping("/api/facturas")
    public void deleteAllFacturas() {

        facturaService.deleteAllFacturas();


    }
}
```

[schema.sql]

```
DROP TABLE factura IF EXISTS;
DROP TABLE facturas IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE facturas (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nro_factura INT NOT NULL,
    fecha_factura DATE NOT NULL,
    id_cliente BIGINT NOT NULL,
    id_empresa BIGINT NOT NULL,
    id_producto BIGINT NOT NULL,
    cantidad INT NOT NULL,
    precio_unitario VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    precio_total VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

[data.sql]

```
INSERT INTO facturas (nro_factura,fecha_factura,id_cliente,id_empresa,id_producto,cantidad,precio_unitario,precio_total) VALUES (4444,'2022-07-04',1,1,1,2,'1000','2000');
```

Comment: sorry Scary Wombat, i don't get it

Comment: yes, but no, since the problem comes with this single entity, the other entities can get the requests correctly

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is that these mappings are incorrect

```java
    @Column(name = "id_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @Column(name = "id_empresa")
    private Empresa empresa;

    @Column(name = "id_producto")
    private Producto producto;
```

You can't just use associations in the mapping, like other fields.
You have to explain to Hibernate, how they are implemented on the database level. For example, using a join table or a foreign key.

To create an association via a foreign key, you need to use `@JoinColumn` and `@ManyToOne` annotation

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_empresa")
    private Empresa empresa;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_producto")
    private Producto producto;
```

You can find more options here
[what is @JoinColumn and how it is used in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542849/3405171)

Comment: Thank you very much v.ladynev! You have made my day, one question...
to receive those JoinColumn and ManyToOne annotations on the other entities, should I do it via a MappedBy ?

Comment: @NazarenoGarma Yes. But keep in mind that you don't always need `@OneToMany` part of the association. For example for `Cliente`. It is tabular data, like `User`, `Role` (if it means Client). Also even if you have `@OneToMany` part, sometimes, It is much better to use `@ManyToOne` part to add a record to the database.

Comment: Thank you very much, you deserve the best, I thought it would take me a long time to understand relationships, you have taken a big thorn out of me :)

Comment: @NazarenoGarma Sure

Comment: good spotting..