# Join query shows error in spring boot but the same query gives the result in postgresql

Tags: java, api, jpa

I tried to apply inner join in the spring boot application to get desired columns from the two tables namely, vehicle and customer.

I have two entities i.e, Vehicle and Customer

```java
package com.eichers.vehicleapi.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

    //define fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "chassis")
    private int chassis;

    @Column(name = "regno")
    private String regno;

    @Column(name = "customerconsent")
    private String customerconsent;

    //define constructors


    public Vehicle(String regno, String customerconsent) {
        this.regno = regno;
        this.customerconsent = customerconsent;
    }

    public Vehicle() {
    }


    //define getter and setter

    public int getChassis() {
        return chassis;
    }

    public void setChassis(int chassis) {
        this.chassis = chassis;
    }

    public String getRegno() {
        return regno;
    }

    public void setRegno(String regno) {
        this.regno = regno;
    }

    public String getCustomerconsent() {
        return customerconsent;
    }

    public void setCustomerconsent(String customerconsent) {
        this.customerconsent = customerconsent;
    }


    //define toString method


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle{" +
                "chassis=" + chassis +
                ", regno='" + regno + '\'' +
                ", customerconsent='" + customerconsent + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Customer entity

```java
package com.eichers.vehicleapi.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    //define fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastname;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="chassis_id")
    private Vehicle vehicle;

//constructor
  public Customer(String type, String firstname, String lastname, Vehicle vehicle) {
        this.type = type;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

}
```

Details class

```java
package com.eichers.vehicleapi.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;

public class Details {

    @Column(name="chassis")
    private int chassis;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="regno")
    private String regno;

    @Column(name="customerconsent")
    private String customerconsent;

// Details class for the final table which I expect
    public Details() {
    }

    public Details(int chassis, String firstname, String lastname, String regno, String customerconsent) {
        this.chassis = chassis;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.regno = regno;
        this.customerconsent = customerconsent;
    }

    public int getChassis() {
        return chassis;
    }

    public void setChassis(int chassis) {
        this.chassis = chassis;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getRegno() {
        return regno;
    }

    public void setRegno(String regno) {
        this.regno = regno;
    }

    public String getCustomerconsent() {
        return customerconsent;
    }

    public void setCustomerconsent(String customerconsent) {
        this.customerconsent = customerconsent;
    }   
}
```

The query which I wrote for the join:

```
 @Override
    public List<Details> getDetails() {
       
        TypedQuery<Details> theQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT Vehicle.chassis, Customer.firstname, Customer.lastname, Vehicle.regno, Vehicle.customerconsent FROM Customer JOIN Vehicle ON Customer.chassis_id = vehicle.chassis",Details.class);
        //get the list
        List<Details> details = theQuery.getResultList();

        return details;
    }
```

The error that I am getting is

```
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret path expression 'Customer.chassis_id'
```

In the above I don't know what to do with Customer.chassis*_id as chassis_id is the name of the attribute in the database.*

How should I use the foreign key correctly in the spring boot query? As this is fine when I run it in Postgresql it gives results.

```sql
SELECT vehicle.chassis, customer.first_name, customer.last_name, vehicle.regno, vehicle.customerconsent FROM vehicle JOIN customer ON vehicle.chassis = customer.chassis_id;
```

```
 chassis | first_name | last_name |   regno    |         customerconsent
---------+------------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------
       2 | Kunal      | Ganjawala | 122yamaha  | it is great driving yamaha
       3 | Mohit      | Chauhan   | 122hero    | it is great driving hero
    3000 | Sonu       | Nigam     | 122hero    | it is great driving hero
    3001 | Arijit     | Singh     | 129jawa    | it is great driving jawa
    3003 | Armaan     | Mallik    | 1230pulsor | pulsor makes me feel like flying
(5 rows)
```

The above is what I expect but it is not happening.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542849/2310289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using JPQL and in join you using actual column name instead of property name. JPQL uses property name not column name.

Update your query as following.

```
SELECT v.chassis, c.firstname, c.lastname, v.regno, v.customerconsent FROM Customer c JOIN c.vehicle v
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped! It required an alias which I need to put in the query and also used a tuple class to store the results. Then it worked and I am getting the expected results.

Comment: Yes. If you think answer helped you. Please accept it as answer so others can get help if they have similiar question.