# Sprind Data JPA OneToOne and ManyToOne Relations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity-relationship

I have 2 entity named `Machine` and `MachineType`. `Machine` can have only one `MachineType` but `MachineType` can have more than one or none `Machine`. I try tons of relation annotation but I miss something.

**Machine**

```
@Entity
public class Machine {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "machine_id")
private Long machineId;

@OneToOne(???)
private MachineType machineType;

@Column(name = "machine_name")
private String MachineName;

//getters and setters
}
```

**MachineType**

```
@Entity
public class MachineType {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long machineTypeId;

@ManyToOne(???)
private List<Machine> machines;

@Column(name = "machine_type_name")
private String machineTypeName;

//getters and setters
}
```

I dont understand `mappedBy` and `@JoinColumn` correctly and I stuck right now. When should I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont understand mappedBy and @JoinColumn correctly and I stuck right now.

**mappedBy** = relationship field or property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship. In this example, this is the field **machineType** annotated by `@ManyToOne` annotation.

**@JoinColumn** = the name of the foreign key column in the database. This means when you define the tables, for example, `MACHINE` and `MACHINE_TYPE`, you add the primary key of the `MACHINE_TYPE` table into the `MACHINE` and thereby creating a relationship between the tables. This field is called foreign key, because it is pointing to another record in another table in the database. The name of this column is specified in through this annotation.

**Note**: the **mappedBy** element is needed only if you want a bidirectional relationship. Otherwise, it is not required.

```
@Entity
public class Machine {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "machine_id")
    private Long machineId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="name_of_foreignkey")
    private MachineType machineType;

    @Column(name = "machine_name")
    private String MachineName;

   //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class MachineType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long machineTypeId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="machineType")
    private List<Machine> machines;

    @Column(name = "machine_type_name")
    private String machineTypeName;

    //getters and setters
 }
```

I removed `strategy = GenerationType.TABLE` from the `GeneratedValue` annotation because it will not work as you specified. If you want to use a table generator (which is the recommended way of generating primary key) you must do more than just specifying as you did.

Answer (score 0):

In Machine, you should use ManyToOne relationship. If you want bi-directional association, you can add OneToMany in MachineType.   MappedBy vs JoinColumn is answered at 
[JPA JoinColumn vs mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)