# Hibernate mappedBy gives com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-initialization

Just need a quick Help from you all. I have used `mappedBy` Instead of `@JoinColumn` just for performance Optimization:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user")
```

I have been advised to set `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`.
But I don't want to do that. Is there any other way to get lazily Loaded Collection Objects.
Or should I use `@JoinColumn` for that?
And `mappedBy` is then how useful for other if not able to read it lazily.

Sample entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users,uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames= "username"))
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {
   private Set<IDPMaster> idpMaster;
    public void setIdpMaster(Set<IDPMaster> idpMaster) {
        this.idpMaster = idpMaster;
    }
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user")
    public Set<IDPUserManagerMapping> getIdpMapping() {
        return idpMapping;
    }
    //Getters and Setters 
    }


@Entity
@Table(name="IDP_Master",schema="eb")
public class IDPMaster implements Serializable {
    private Users idpUsers;
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="paticipant_id",nullable=false)
    public Users getIdpUsers() {
        return idpUsers;
    }
    public void setIdpUsers(Users idpUsers) {
        this.idpUsers = idpUsers;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**mappedBy** can be used only in one entity i.e. the Parent entity whereas @JoinColumn can be used on the both side of the relationship. See [JPA JoinColumn vs mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby) for difference. Can you show the sample entities that you have created.

Also you need not to specify fetch=FetchType.LAZY because by default the fetchType is always lazy in Hibernate. In JPA however the fetch type is different for different mappings.

Edited..
The field name provided in the **mappedBy** should be **"idpUsers"** instead of **"users"**. It should match the variable name in the child Entity.