# Spring mvc hibernate, primary key not changing value of foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have a relationship one-to one:

**User:**

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
private String firstName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "userId")
Employee employee;
```

**Employee :**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
int id;
@NotNull
int userId;
String lastName;
```

**userRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> { }
```

So I am creating an User and Employee by that way:

```
User user = new User();
user.setFirstName("George");

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.SetLastName("Iliev");

user.setEmployee(employee);
userRepository.save(user);
```

The Id of user is auto incrementing and working. But when I select all from employees, the userId is always 0. Even if I insert 10 users + 10 employees, each userId is = 0.

Why ? And how to fix it ?

EDIT:
[Exception thrown:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKZ2u.png)

[Controller code for inserting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rffnM.png)

[**User**.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1DF5.png)

[**Employer**.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMxO4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is `userId` always `0`?

Your `userId` property does not have any annotations that tell JPA that it is a foreign key. Therefore, `userId` is treated like a normal field. When `Employee` gets instantiated, `userId` will have no value. When a `primitive int` has no value, it defaults to `0`.

#### Proposed solution

Change the property from `int userId` to `User user` and annotate it with the following `@OneToOne` annotation:

```
@NotNull
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee")
User user;
```

Then to get the `userId`, simply call `user.getId()`.

#### How to use @JoinColumn

This specifies the column in your table. To keep things simple, use it to annotate your foreign key property and give it a suitable name. Make sure it doesn't conflict with existing column names.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
Employee employee;
```

You can leave out `referencedColumnName`, as this will automatically be set to the primary key column name of the referenced entity.

For a more detailed answer on the annotations, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby) for a nice example.

Comment: I added it and got exception: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.foo.dto.Employee.userId, referenced property unknown: int.employee

Comment: Okay, but if I change userId to User user, how should I map this: 

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "userId")
Employee employee;

Comment: ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null'

Comment: Did you remove the `USER_ID` column in your database? If not, please delete the column. Because it is now named `employee_id`, the column is unused.

Comment: Yes, I dropped all the tables and still:
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=user,

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace (perhaps edit it in your original question). That little snippet error does not really help.

Comment: I added some pictures. If we solve this out, I will be really thankfull !!!

Comment: The error is saying the property `user` in `Employer` is `null`. This makes sense, because in your method `test()` you've never set `user`. To do so, use: `employer.setUser(userTwo);`

Comment: Now it is inserting only User, and no Employer. Also user field EmployerId is null ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

```
@NotNull
int userId;
```

To

```
@NotNull
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee")
User user;
```

Second, change

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "userId")
Employee employee;
```

To

```
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    Employee employee;
```

Because you already have column named "id" above (your primary key). Also you have to delete `useId` column from employee table.

Comment: ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=user,