# Saving object with one to many unidirectional relation does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have order and it can have many status. Trying to save new status seems not working with unidirectional relationship. 
Is that right I can not save status with unidirectional relation from order to status as shown in my code? What are possible way to get that saved?

Table : ORDER(PK_ORDER_ID, ORDER_NO)

Table : ORDER_STATUS(PK_ORDER_STATUS_ID, FK_ORDER_ID, STATUS)

Order class like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PK_ORDER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "FK_ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName = "PK_ORDER_ID")
private Set<OrderStatus> orderStatus;
}
```

OrderStatus class like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_STATUS")
public class OrderStatus {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PK_ORDER_STATUS_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "STATUS")
private String status;

public OrderStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}
```

Somewhere is other file

```
order.getStatus().add(new OrderStatus("new"));
```

The database code which save the changes is -

```
@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED)
public U merge(U EntityToUpdate) {
    return em.merge(EntityToUpdate);
}
```

It give following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: (conn:40) Field 'FK_ORDER_ID' doesn't have value
Query is: insert into ORDER_STATUS (STATUS) values (?), parameters ['new']
```

Comment: Where is the code that does the "save"??? including transaction boundaries

Comment: You need to put ManyToOne annotation above your JoinColumn, check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11939045/6221731

Comment: This doesn't run on hibernate.