# Hibernate manyToOne FK not saving

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, foreign-keys

Im trying to save List of class instances inside a parent object, with hibernate. Child instance should map to parent by parents ID "CONTRACTID", which is generated.

**PARENT:**

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CONTRACTID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_Sequence", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ_CONTRACT")
    private Long contract_id;
```

and then

```
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CustomerGroup.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "contractId")
    private List<CustomerGroup> customerGroups;
```

**CHILD:**

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRACTID", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="CONTRACTID_FK"))
    private ContractHolder contractId;
```

also tried without `foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="CONTRACTID_FK")`

I see in database that both fields are existing, parents ID is generated as expected on .save but the FK field of CustomerGroup stays as null when parent is saved.

What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Save code is very simple line in Database.class
after setting all the needed values for parent object, also the List of CustomerGroup is set to parent object and saved properly but not the FK autogenerated id

```
contractRepo.save(contract);
```

EDIT2:

and if i try to set parent object to @JoinColumn of childeren before saving. like

```
customerGroup.setContractId(contractHolder);
```

i get what seems to be an infinite loop.
goddamn

Comment: show the code how you are saving parent object ?

Comment: @Dev911 added some code

Comment: I think you missed up the mapping because parent class mapped @OneToMany with CustomerGroup and another side (child class) is ContractHolder

Comment: @AngadBansode im trying to save List of CustomerGroup's inside one ContractHolder class instance. i dont really understand what you are saying. They are suppose to be different classes?

Comment: You have to set the `ContractHolder` in the `CustomerGroup`.

Comment: yeah, can you tell me how not to get infinite loop while retrieving it tho? Also if you put that as an answer i can accept it. @K.Nicholas

Comment: Naw, you should do your own debugging. Start with posting code that runs. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/whats-the-difference-between-joincolumn-and-mappedby-when-using-a-jpa-onetoma. Turn on the SQL output and see what is going on: logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

Comment: Yeah no prob. i already solved the problem, just thought if you have some information to clear it further. Either way, if you post your comment from above as answer i can accept that (You have to set the ContractHolder in the CustomerGroup.) @K.Nicholas