# Why is it not possible to use mappedBy in a ManyToOne bidirectional relationship?

Tags: spring, jpa

I was trying to make a bidirectional ManyToOne/OneToMany relationship in JPA and I wasn't allowed to use the MappedBy in the ManyToOne side, only in the OneToMany.

I made some research and it said that the many side cannot own the relationship in a bidirectional ManyToOne/OneToMany relationship.

-What does it mean that one side "owns" the relationship?
-why can't I use the mappedBy in a ManyToOne relationship

Comment: [answers of this question can help you to understand more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA JoinColumn vs mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)

Comment: For what you seem to what, you don't need to use mappedBy at all. Create a unidirectional OneToMany. Then create a unidirectional ManyToOne and make it read only (insertable/updatable=false) using the same foreign key setup as is in the OneToMany. MappedBy just tells JPA which side controls the foreign key, and it is much more common that the entity with the table that holds the foreign key should be the one to 'own' and control setting the FK value