# What is the equivalent keyword for ‘inverse’ in Hibernate annotations?

Tags: hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [inverse=true in JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865285/inverse-true-in-jpa-annotations)

Can anyone tell me what the equivalent keyword for ‘inverse’ is in Hibernate annotations.

Comment: Do you mean use a inverse orderby? If you are looking for it you can annotate it doing @OrderBy("columnName desc")

Comment: Hope this can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865285/inverse-true-in-jpa-annotations