# Why hibernate runs delete and insert commands for embaddable objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create a simple example to understand how collection of basic and embaddable types works in Hibernate.

I have created a `User` entity with a set of `nickNames` and also a set of `addresses`. Here are my Java classes:

`User.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Nicknames", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "nickname")
    private Set<String> nickNames = new HashSet<String>();
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Addresses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "street1", column = @Column(name = "fld_street")) })
    public Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, Address... addresses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.addresses.addAll(Arrays.asList(addresses));
    }

    public void addNickName(String... nickNames) {
        this.nickNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(nickNames));
    }
// Setters & Getters
}
```

`Address.java`

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street1;
    public Address() {}
    public Address(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return street1;
    }
// Setters & Getters
}
```

Now I have created a simple program to create users in database and then show the list of users. Here is my code:

```
private static void saveUsers() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        User user = new User("User", new Address("abc"),
                new Address("xyz"));
        user1.addNickName("alpha", "beta");
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

private static void showUsers() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User").list();   
    for (User user : users) {
        System.out.println(user.getName() + " -- > " + user.getNickNames()
                + " --> " + user.getAddresses());
    }    
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

When I run this program, I observed that hibernate issues below set of commands:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_2_, user0_.name as name2_2_ from TB_User user0_
Hibernate: select nicknames0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, nicknames0_.nickname as nickname2_1_0_ from Nicknames nicknames0_ where nicknames0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select addresses0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, addresses0_.fld_street as fld_street2_0_0_ from Addresses addresses0_ where addresses0_.user_id=?
User -- > [alpha, beta] --> [xyz, abc]

Hibernate: delete from Addresses where user_id=?
Hibernate: insert into Addresses (user_id, fld_street) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from Addresses where user_id=?
Hibernate: insert into Addresses (user_id, fld_street) values (?, ?)
```

If I try to get the list of addresses using `user.getAddresses()` with in `session`, then Hibernate deletes & re-inserts records in `Addresses` table.

Why hibernate tries to delete and re-create records in `Addresses` table, as this causes performance issue. Also why it is not applicable to basic types like `nickNames` in my example and not running update commands for the property `nickNames`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is related to the fact, that there is **not** bi-directional mapping. To understand that in depth - please read this article:

- [inverse = “true” example and explanation](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/)

And here is the way how to do that with annotation:

- [inverse=true in JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865285/)

Let me cite from the answer:

> I found an answer to this. The **`mappedBy`** attribute of `@OneToMany` annotation behaves the same as inverse = true in the xml file.

Some summary:

Hibernate can issue SQL statements which we would expect. But only, if we do have bidirectional mapping in place.

Then, the other end (address) will be driving the persistence. It will/**must** know about its parent - and that's why some direct UPDATE statements could be issued.

So, if we want to avoid DELETE and INSERT, we have to use the inverse mapping. Hibernate will issue more "expectable" SQL.

Comment: As I am using `Address` as `@Embeddable` I think I cannot use `@OneToMany/@ManyToOne`. So it means as hibernate cannot use `update` commands as `Address` is not having any identifier then it is deleting and re-inserting records. Is my understanding correct? So it means we cannot control the generated SQL if we want to use Embeddable collections.

Comment: You've absolutely got the point. The only way how to optimize SQL generated here - is bidirectional mapping. If this is @Embeddable... there is no way for **sure**. *(if we would think about it, it is logical)* ... sorry I do not have "the answer"... but hope that helped somehow ;)

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite old, but might be relevant to sombody. Another tip that helped in my case: if you can separate reads from writes, consider using

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

That makes underlying JPA framework know that no modifications are expected in the current transaction. In practice, Hibernate no longer would run `delete` + `insert` when you merely want fetching some data.