# Annotation for all-delete-orphan in hibernate 4.1.4

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations, all-delete-orphan

I'm new to this hibernate annotation. I want to convert this xml mapping into annotations:

```
<map name="Text" table="JAV_TEXT" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="FK_GUID"/>
    <map-key column="TEXT_GUID" type="string"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.TextPO"/>
</map>
```

This is what I have done:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=com.TextPO.class)
@Cascade({CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
@JoinColumn(name="FK_GUID")
@MapKey(name="TEXT_GUID")
private Map<String, PersistentObject> text = new HashMap<String, PersistentObject>();
```

But `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` is deprecated, so how do I represent `all-delete-orphan` through annotations?
I'm using hibernate 4.1.4.

Comment: use `orphanRemoval=true` in your `@OneToMany`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes in `Hibernate 4.1.4` version `delete-orphan` is deprecated, now in `Hibernate` and `JPA 2.0` you can use `orphanRemoval` instead:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
```

Your mapping should be like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=com.TextPO.class, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="FK_GUID")
@MapKey(name="TEXT_GUID")
private Map<String, PersistentObject> text = new HashMap<String, PersistentObject>();
```

And also remove the `@Cascade` annotation you can use it as an attribute of the `@OneToMany` annotation like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=com.TextPO.class, orphanRemoval = true)
```

Take a look at **[this Example](http://dinukaroshan.blogspot.com/2011/09/hibernate-by-example-part-1-orphan.html)** for further reading.

**EDIT:**

To give the `inverse="true"` property in your mapping you just need to specify the `mappedBy` attribute in your @`OneToMany` annotation to refer the owning part of the relation, like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=com.TextPO.class, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy= "theOneSide")
```

Here the `theOneSide` is used as an example you just need to specify the field name used in the other side class of the mapping, for example:

```
@ManyToOne
private MyClass theOneSide;
```

Take a look at **[inverse=true in JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865285/inverse-true-in-jpa-annotations)** for further information.

Comment: I have doubt like how to give annotation for "inverse = true"

Comment: you can simply add the mappedBy attribute to the `@OneToMany` annotation, it will replace the `inverse="true"`.

Comment: It is showing like "The attribute orphanRemoval is undefined for the annotation type OneToMany"..

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of Hibernate? are you sure it's 4.1.4? you can see in [the OneToMany Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#orphanRemoval()) it states that it's there since JPA2.0, and make sure it's correctly spelled `orphanRemoval`, also make sure you imported `javax.persistence.OneToMany; `.

Comment: so true if you use mappedBy you have to remove cascade

Comment: In your EDIT you've forgotten the "cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }" - to replace "all-delete-orphan" and not only "delete-orphan"