# ORMLite foreign @DatabaseField with inverse mapping?

Tags: ormlite

I'm implementing a small project and I'm wondering if ORMLite supports inverse mapping for `@DatabaseMapping`s. What I am looking for is this similar to JPA's/Hibernates's inverse mapping. Following, hypothetical and rather silly example, a table `BlogPost`:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class BlogPost {
  @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
  private Author owner;
}
```

and the according `Author` class, not really that important:

```
@DatabaseTable public class Author { }
```

This results in the following SQL (just the relevant parts):

`CREATE TABLE blogpost ( ... , owner_id INTEGER NOT NULL, ... )
CREATE TABLE author ( ... )`

See how table blogpost now has a foreign key for author. However, I'd prefer it the other way around, i.e. author should have a blogpost_id foreign key. (I told you it was a silly example... ;).

With inverse mapping I could utilize cascades for deletes but I haven't found anything in the ORMlite docs about this. Is it not a feature or am I just missing something?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer @ilikeorangutans?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't work on that for a while. Thank you for your response.  See my comments below.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a bit confused by the question but I thought I'd try to answer it anyway.

I don't understand how that would work @ilikeorangutans.  I assume that there are multiple blogposts for a single author? So how could there be a single `blogpost_id` on the account channel? You could have a join table which contains an `author_id` and a `blogpost_id` but that just adds complexity.

If you take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439756/hibernate-inverse-in-mapping-file) and this [webpage](http://itefforts.blogspot.com/2007/10/understanding-mapping-attribute.html), you can see that Hibernate's inverse mapping is about who controls the relationship and is responsible for updating the rows.  In both cases, `BlogPost` would have an `author_id` and not the other way around.

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) *does* support the concept of "foreign collections" where you can add a `BlogPost` to the database by adding it to the collection in the `Author` object.  For more information see the [foreign collection documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection).

Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: The assumption is that there's only one author per post. I looked into foreign collections, but they don't do what I want. The whole idea is that I can use cascades on delete to delete depending rows automatically, for example if you delete the author, *all* his posts are deleted. Not sure if that makes sense

Comment: Yeah, ORMLite doesn't support cascading.  Not sure it ever will.  It's hard to balance the "lite" and the features people want.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789075/deleting-using-ormlite-on-android