# Deleting using ormlite on android?

Tags: android, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have a Client bean ,

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "client_id",generatedId = true,useGetSet = true)
private Integer clientId;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "client_nom",useGetSet = true)
private String clientNom;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "city_id",foreign = true,useGetSet = true)
private City city;
```

and a City bean ,

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "city_id",generatedId = true,useGetSet = true)
private Integer cityId;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "city_name",useGetSet = true)
private String cityName;
@ForeignCollectionField
private ForeignCollection<Client> clientList;
```

Those beans are just an example but let's say , I want to delete all the clients having as foreign city cityId when deleting a city.

How is that possible please ?

Answer (score 51):

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not support cascading deletes @Majid.  That is currently outside of what it considers to be "lite".  If you delete the `city` then you need to delete the `clients` by hand.

One way to ensure this would be to have a `CityDao` class that overrides the `delete()` method and issues the delete through the `ClientDao` at the same time.  Something like:

```
public class CityDao extends BaseDaoImpl<City, Integer> {
    private ClientDao clientDao;
    public CityDao(ConnectionSource cs, ClientDao clientDao) {
        super(cs, City.class);
        this.clientDao = clientDao;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public int delete(City city) {
        // first delete the clients that match the city's id
        DeleteBuilder db = clientDao.deleteBuilder();
        db.where().eq("city_id", city.getId());
        clientDao.delete(db.prepare());
        // then call the super to delete the city
        return super.delete(city);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of how would I instantiate CityDao. For instance in my app I have "private ArtistDao artistDao = null" and "artistDao = new ArtistDao(Artist.class);". I don't know how to migrate to custom extended class, I get cast exceptions and I don't know how and where to supply the connection source.

Comment: I don't understand @SpeedDemon.   Your `ArtistDao` must be a concrete class if you instantiate it.  The `CityDao` in my post shows how to extend `BaseDaoImpl`.

Comment: I guess your constructor has to throw SQLException

Answer (score 4):

To implement cascading while using ORMLite on Android you need to enable foreign key restraints as described here:

(API level > 16)

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()){
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

For API level < 16 please read:
[Foreign key constraints in Android using SQLite? on Delete cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545558/foreign-key-constraints-in-android-using-sqlite-on-delete-cascade)

Then use columnDefinition annotation to define cascading deletes. Ex:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true,
columnDefinition = "integer references my_table(id) on delete cascade")
private MyTable table;
```

This is assuming the table/object name is "my_table", as described here: [Creating foreign key constraints in ORMLite under SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090075/creating-foreign-key-constraints-in-ormlite-under-sqlite)